# Returning a closure from a function

Tags: rust

**Note**: This question was asked before Rust's first stable release. There have been lots of changes since and the syntax used in the function is not even valid anymore. Still, Shepmaster's answer is excellent and makes this question worth keeping.

---

Finally unboxed closures have landed, so I am experimenting with them to see what you can do.

I have this simple function:

```
fn make_adder(a: int, b: int) -> || -> int {
    || a + b
}
```

However, I get a `missing lifetime specifier [E0106]` error. I have tried to fix this by changing the return type to `||: 'static -> int`, but then I get another error `cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements`.

If I understand correctly, the closure is unboxed so it owns `a` and `b`. It seems very strange to me that it needs a lifetime. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

As of Rust 1.26, you can use [`impl trait`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1522-conservative-impl-trait.md):

```
fn make_adder(a: i32) -> impl Fn(i32) -> i32 {
    move |b| a + b
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", make_adder(1)(2));
}
```

This allows returning an *unboxed* closure even though it is impossible to specify the exact type of the closure.

This will **not** help you if any of these are true:

1. You are targeting Rust before this version
2. You have any kind of conditional in your function:

   ```
   fn make_adder(a: i32) -> impl Fn(i32) -> i32 {
       if a > 0 {
           move |b| a + b
       } else {
           move |b| a - b
       }
   }
   ```

   Here, there isn't a single return type; each closure has a unique, un-namable type.
3. You need to be able to name the returned type for any reason:

   ```
   struct Example<F>(F);

   fn make_it() -> Example<impl Fn()> {
       Example(|| println!("Hello"))
   }

   fn main() {
       let unnamed_type_ok = make_it();
       let named_type_bad: /* No valid type here */ = make_it();
   }
   ```

   You cannot ([yet](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63066)) use `impl SomeTrait` as a variable type.

In these cases, you need to use indirection. The common solution is a *trait object*, as described in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25447913/155423).

Comment: Is this still the idiomatic way to do this in 2021 (1.49)?

Comment: @detly yes, it is.

Answer (score 32):

It is possible to return closures inside `Box`es, that is, as trait objects implementing certain trait:

```
fn make_adder(a: i32) -> Box<dyn Fn(i32) -> i32> {
    Box::new(move |b| a + b)
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", make_adder(1)(2));
}
```

(try it [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4f89374cc538bd639d8a&version=stable))

There is also [an RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/105) ([its tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/518)) on adding unboxed abstract return types which would allow returning closures by value, without boxes, but this RFC was postponed. According to discussion in that RFC, it seems that some work is done on it recently, so it is possible that unboxed abstract return types will be available relatively soon.

Comment: Is the boxing still going to be necessary with the new `move` keyword? Doesn't that make the closure independent of the stack frame, and its size known at compile time?

Comment: @RenatoZannon, the problem with returning unboxed closures is not their dependency on the stack frame (they already *are* independent unless they capture local references) or unknown size. Because they're anonymous structs implementing certain traits, there is just no way to specify their type in return position without boxing.

Comment: Oh, I see, so it's a type system/syntax issue. Thanks!

Comment: The linked code sample (http://is.gd/d2DANn) as of the time of this comment reports errors about conflicting lifetime requirements, and I'm unsure how to interpret the error. (preemption to those unfamiliar with play-rust: reproducing the error can be done by going to the link and simply clicking 'evaluate')

Comment: @user, this is known problem, there is a bug on that on Rust issue tracker, but I can't provide a link now, I'm on mobile phone.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Just found it after commenting: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/11740

Comment: @VladimirMatveev I just updated your first code example, please double check that it still conveys your intention.

Comment: << very noob, just trying my first lines of Rust: When I add a semi colon to the `Box::new` line, where the closure is returned, the compiler suddenly says: `error: unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations or generic parameter binding required [E0282]` - What difference does the semi colon make?

Comment: @Zelphir, this is a consequence of that Rust is an expression-based language. You can find more [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/functions.html#expressions-vs-statements).

Answer (score 7):

The `||` syntax is still the old boxed closures, so this doesn't work for the same reason it didn't previously.

And, it won't work even using the correct boxed closure syntax `|&:| -> int`, since it is literally is just sugar for certain traits. At the moment, the sugar syntax is `|X: args...| -> ret`, where the `X` can be `&`, `&mut` or nothing, corresponding to the [`Fn`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/ops/trait.Fn.html), [`FnMut`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html), [`FnOnce`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html) traits, you can also write `Fn<(args...), ret>` etc. for the non-sugared form. The sugar is likely to be changing (possibly something like `Fn(args...) -> ret`).

Each unboxed closure has a unique, unnameable type generated internally by the compiler: the only way to talk about unboxed closures is via generics and trait bounds. In particular, writing

```
fn make_adder(a: int, b: int) -> |&:| -> int {
    |&:| a + b
}
```

is like writing

```
fn make_adder(a: int, b: int) -> Fn<(), int> {
    |&:| a + b
}
```

i.e. saying that `make_adder` returns an unboxed trait value; which doesn't make much sense at the moment. The first thing to try would be

```
fn make_adder<F: Fn<(), int>>(a: int, b: int) -> F {
    |&:| a + b
}
```

but this is saying that `make_adder` is returning any `F` that the *caller* chooses, while we want to say it returns some fixed (but "hidden") type. This required [abstract return types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/105), which says, basically, "the return value implements this trait" while still being unboxed and statically resolved. In the language of that (temporarily closed) RFC,

```
fn make_adder(a: int, b: int) -> impl Fn<(), int> {
    |&:| a + b
}
```

Or with the closure sugar.

(Another minor point: I'm not 100% sure about unboxed closures, but the old closures certainly still capture things by-reference which is another thing that sinks the code as proposed in the issue. This is being rectified in [#16610](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/16610).)

Comment: Is this answer still relevant in modern Rust?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to implement a closure based counter:

```rs
fn counter() -> impl FnMut() -> i32 {
    let mut value = 0;

    move || -> i32 {
        value += 1;
        return value;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut incre = counter();
    println!("Count 1: {}", incre());
    println!("Count 2: {}", incre());
}
```