# How do I store a closure in a struct in Rust?

Tags: closures, rust

Before Rust 1.0, I could write a structure using this obsolete closure syntax:

```
struct Foo {
    pub foo: |usize| -> usize,
}
```

Now I can do something like:

```
struct Foo<F: FnMut(usize) -> usize> {
    pub foo: F,
}
```

But then what's the type of a `Foo` object I create?

```
let foo: Foo<???> = Foo { foo: |x| x + 1 };
```

I could also use a reference:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    pub foo: &'a mut FnMut(usize) -> usize,
}
```

I think this is slower because

1. the pointer dereference
2. there's no specialization for the type of `FnMut` that actually ends up being used

Answer (score 63, accepted):

For what type you'd use in your third code snippet, there *isn't* one; closure types are anonymous and cannot be directly named.  Instead, you'd write:

```
let foo = Foo { foo: |x| x + 1 };
```

If you're writing code in a context where you *need* to specify that you want a `Foo`, you'd write:

```
let foo: Foo<_> = Foo { foo: |x| x + 1 };
```

The `_` tells the type system to infer the actual generic type for you.

The general rule of thumb as to *which* to use, in descending order:

- Generic parameters: `struct Foo<F: FnMut(usize) -> usize>`.  This is the most efficient, but it does mean that a specific `Foo` instance can only ever store *one* closure, since every closure has a different concrete type.
- Trait references: `&'a mut dyn FnMut(usize) -> usize`.  There's a pointer indirection, but now you can store a reference to any closure that has a compatible call signature.
- Boxed closures: `Box<dyn FnMut(usize) -> usize>`.  This involves allocating the closure on the heap, but you don't have to worry about lifetimes.  As with a reference, you can store any closure with a compatible signature.

## Before Rust 1.0

Closures that used the `||` syntax were references to closures stored on the stack, making them equivalent to `&'a mut FnMut(usize) -> usize`.  Old-style `proc`s were heap-allocated and were equivalent to `Box<dyn FnOnce(usize) -> usize>` (you can only call a `proc` once).

Comment: Is it possible to create functions like `compose` or `apply` that work generically over the 3 different traits `Fn`, `FnMut` and `FnOnce`? I find myself having to create 3 different versions of `compose` or `apply` to satisfy the 3 traits of closures.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai If you need more details, you should ask a new question, but no, I don't believe it is.  Keep in mind, however, that all `Fn`s can be used as `FnMut`s, and all `Fn`s and `FnMut`s can be used as `FnOnce`s.

Answer (score 138):

Complementing [the existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27832320/155423) with some more code for demonstration purposes:

### Unboxed closure

Use a generic type:

```
struct Foo<F>
where
    F: Fn(usize) -> usize,
{
    pub foo: F,
}

impl<F> Foo<F>
where
    F: Fn(usize) -> usize,
{
    fn new(foo: F) -> Self {
        Self { foo }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo { foo: |a| a + 1 };
    (foo.foo)(42);
    
    (Foo::new(|a| a + 1).foo)(42);
}
```

### Boxed trait object

```
struct Foo {
    pub foo: Box<dyn Fn(usize) -> usize>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn new(foo: impl Fn(usize) -> usize + 'static) -> Self {
        Self { foo: Box::new(foo) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo {
        foo: Box::new(|a| a + 1),
    };
    (foo.foo)(42);
    
    (Foo::new(|a| a + 1).foo)(42);
}
```

### Trait object reference

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    pub foo: &'a dyn Fn(usize) -> usize,
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn new(foo: &'a dyn Fn(usize) -> usize) -> Self {
        Self { foo }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo { foo: &|a| a + 1 };
    (foo.foo)(42);
    
    (Foo::new(&|a| a + 1).foo)(42);
}
```

### Function pointer

```
struct Foo {
    pub foo: fn(usize) -> usize,
}

impl Foo {
    fn new(foo: fn(usize) -> usize) -> Self {
        Self { foo }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo { foo: |a| a + 1 };
    (foo.foo)(42);
    
    (Foo::new(|a| a + 1).foo)(42);
}
```

---

> what's the type of a `Foo` object I create?

It's an unnameable, automatically generated type.

> I could also use a reference [...] slower because [...] the pointer deref [...] no specialization

Perhaps, but it can be much easier on the caller.

See also:

- [How do I call a function through a member variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27994509/155423)
- [Returning a closure from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25445761/155423)
- [How to return an anonymous type from a trait method without using Box?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49980850/155423)
- [Closures as a type in a Rust struct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41082409/155423)
- [Types of unboxed closures being unique to each](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27874683/155423)
- [Why does passing a closure to function which accepts a function pointer not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52696907/155423)
- [What does "dyn" mean in a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50650070/155423)

Comment: Are any of these choices known to be speedier than the others?

Comment: @DanielV yes, and no. If one of them was guaranteed to be universally better than the others, we wouldn't need the rest. The unboxed closure is probably the default choice and is likely to be the most performant, but the other ones can generate smaller code which might lead to them being more performant.

Comment: rust really needs something like std::function, c++ uniform container for anything invokable.

Comment: what does that "+ 'static" mean in the boxed trait one

Comment: @pm100 [Why is adding a lifetime to a trait with the plus operator (Iterator<Item = &Foo> + 'a) needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42028470/155423); [The compiler suggests I add a 'static lifetime because the parameter type may not live long enough, but I don't think that's what I want](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40053550/155423);

Comment: In the `Unboxed Closure` strategy is it possible to capture the struct which the closure is a member of ?

Comment: @AliSomay Not to capture it, no, but you can pass it as an argument to the the closure itself in certain cases. See [How to use struct self in member method closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48717833/155423); [How can I modify self in a closure called from a member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28597380/155423)

Comment: What are advantages and disadvantages of each approach?

Comment: for the last one in rust 1.65: expected fn pointer, found closure

Comment: What if I want to pass a reference to a Foo to a function? What type should appear in the function signature?

Comment: @Chuck You can [add `&` in the appropriate places](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1756e2bb2ce262e411c71b9a54c65ab0). This will use [higher ranked lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35592750/155423).