# How do I call a function through a member variable?

Tags: rust

Toying with Rust, I'm extracting some code into a class.  To keep it self-contained but separate functionality, I want to hang onto a callback function and call it later.  To keep it simple, including skipping the obvious `fn new()`, we have something like:

```
pub struct Toy {
    go: fn(count: i16) -> String,
}

impl Toy {
    fn lets_go(&mut self, n: i16) -> String {
        self.go(n)
    }
}
```

Building gives me...

```
...path.../src/toy.rs:7:14: 7:19 error: type `&mut toy::Toy` does not implement any method in scope named `go`
...path.../src/toy.rs:7         self.go(n)
```

Presumably, there's a special syntax (or entirely different construct) that makes sense of the `self.go()` call, but I don't see examples or descriptions of comparable situations in any of the documentation, so I'd appreciate any direction.

Obviously, `.go` *could* be of a functor-like class, but that doesn't seem very idiomatic for Rust.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`foo.bar(...)` is always parsed as a method call, it never looks for fields. This avoids ambiguity, especially with traits. One can force it to be a field access by separating the call and the field access into two distinct expressions, for example,

```
let f = self.go;
f(n)
```

Or, better, just `(self.go)(n)`.

Issue [#2392](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/2392) covers improving these diagnostics.

Comment: Excellent.  I should've guessed that parenthesizing would help, but never would have.  Thanks!