# What is the difference between passing a function and a method as a parameter?

Tags: rust

Like in [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27994509/3438854) of mine, I'm refactoring a small Rust project.  Also similar to that question, the compiler and I don't see eye to eye on methods and values.  The error message is very different, though, and this *seems* to potentially involve libraries, [hyper](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper) in this example.

```
/* extern and use directives... */

pub struct WebServer /* with stuff not relevant to the error */;

impl WebServer {
    pub fn serve(&mut self) {
        let server = Server::http(Ipv4Addr(127, 0, 0, 1), 80);
        let mut listening = server.listen(self.return_page).unwrap();
        listening.await();
    }

    fn return_page(&mut self, req: Request, mut res: Response) {
        /* Put the page together */
    }
}
```

When `serve()` and `return_page()` are just functions in `main.rs`, this compiles and runs.

Tucked into a `struct` as above, though, I get the following error:

```
.../src/main.rs:13:48: 13:59 error: attempted to take value of method `return_page` on type `&mut WebServer`
.../src/main.rs:13         let mut listening = server.listen(self.return_page).unwrap();
                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~
.../src/main.rs:13:48: 13:59 help: maybe a `()` to call it is missing? If not, try an anonymous function
.../src/main.rs:13         let mut listening = server.listen(self.return_page).unwrap();
                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

I assume that the parser just needs a nudge in the right direction, but even with the advice I was given on the related problem, I don't see anything in the documentation suggesting a way to say, "no, I really mean the function as a parameter, just like invoked function's signature says I need."  What am I missing, given that the above syntax works outside of a `struct`?

A half-hearted attempt at a closure seemed to be worse *and* the error message still suggested calling `return_page` instead of passing it, but I may well be misunderstanding the usage in this case.

**Edit**:  To clarify the situation after working with the existing answers, the original `return_page()` doesn't have a `self` parameter, of course, which is itself part of the problem.  But it also needs `self` inside the object, because it needs access to member variables.

Answer (score 4):

You can't pass `return_page` directly to `listen`, because [`Handler`](http://hyperium.github.io/hyper/hyper/server/trait.Handler.html) is only implemented on functions that take 2 parameters, a request and a response. `return_page` takes 3 parameters (`self` counts as a parameter).

Try this:

```
let mut listening = server.listen(|&: request, response| self.return_page(request, response)).unwrap();
```

Alternatively, add an `impl` for `Handler` and move your `return_page` function to this `impl`, named `handle`.

```
impl WebServer {
    pub fn serve(&mut self) {
        let server = Server::http(Ipv4Addr(127, 0, 0, 1), 80);
        let mut listening = server.listen(&self).unwrap();
        listening.await();
    }
}

impl<'a> Handler for &'a WebServer {
    fn handle(&self, req: Request, mut res: Response) {
        /* Put the page together */
    }
}
```

Note that `Handler` passes `self` by immutable reference, not by mutable reference. You may need to use [`RefCell`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) to bypass this.

Comment: The `self` parameter stupidly snuck by me, yes, thanks. The closure syntax throws an error that `for<'r,'r>` (with the function's type) isn't implemented for `closure`. Implementing `Handler` gives the same error or (of course) tells me `return_page` doesn't exist (which it doesn't). Am I missing something?

Comment: See my edits. I changed the closure's type, changed the argument to `listen` and changed the `impl Handler` to be on a reference, otherwise I'd have to move `self` into `listen`, which wouldn't be allowed.

Comment: Oh, _obviously_ it should've been `&self`, right! Any idea why `&WebServer` would throw `missing lifetime specifier [E0106]`? I've only see that in relation to functions. (The closure change doesn't seem to change the result, though.)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can use UFCS (Uniform Function Call Syntax):

```
let mut listening = server.listen(WebServer::return_page).unwrap();
```

The long answer is that I doubt this will make your code work. You did not show how `return_page` was defined directly in main, but I guess it was something like `fn return_page(req: Request, mut res: Response)`.

This signature is different from the `return_page` defined as a method of WebServer.
Let's take a look at it:

```
fn return_page(&mut self, req: Request, mut res: Response)
```

this is a function that takes a first argument of type `&mut self`, i.e. `&mut WebServer`. If `listen` was not expecting this signature you will get a "mismatched types" error.

Let me try creating a mock implementation of your code:

```
// serve calls listen passing it return_page. Note that
// the signature of return_page matches the one that
// listen is expecting, fn(u32, u32)
fn serve() {
    listen(return_page)
}

// mock return_page
fn return_page(a: u32, b: u32) { println!("{}, {}", a, b) }

// listen expects a function that takes two u32
// and returns nothing
fn listen( f: fn(u32, u32) ) { f(1, 2) }

fn main() {
    serve();
}
```

[playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=fn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20serve%28%29;%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20serve%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20listen%28return_page%29%0A%7D%0Afn%20return_page%28a:%20u32,%20b:%20u32%29%20%7B%20println!%28%22%7B%7D,%20%7B%7D%22,%20a,%20b%29%20%7D%0A%0Afn%20listen%28%20f:%20fn%28u32,%20u32%29%20%29%20%7B%20f%281,%202%29%20%7D)

Now let's move serve and return_page into an impl, as I think you did:

```
fn listen( f: fn(u32, u32) ) { f(1, 2) }

struct WebServer;
impl WebServer {
    fn serve(&self) {
        listen(WebServer::return_page)
    }
    
    // a method is a function that takes the implementing type
    // as a first parameter. We can use UFCS to invoke it as 
    // a function: WebServer::return_page
    fn return_page(&self, a: u32, b: u32) { println!("{}, {}", a, b) }
}
```

[playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=fn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20listen%28%20f:%20fn%28u32,%20u32%29%20%29%20%7B%20f%281,%202%29%20%7D%0A%0Astruct%20WebServer;%0Aimpl%20WebServer%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20serve%28&self%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20listen%28WebServer::return_page%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20//%20a%20method%20is%20a%20function%20that%20takes%20the%20implementing%20type%0A%20%20%20%20//%20as%20a%20first%20parameter.%20We%20can%20use%20UFCS%20to%20invoke%20it%20as%20%0A%20%20%20%20//%20a%20function:%20WebServer::return_page%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20return_page%28&self,%20a:%20u32,%20b:%20u32%29%20%7B%20println!%28%22%7B%7D,%20%7B%7D%22,%20a,%20b%29%20%7D%0A%7D)

Oops, mismatched types: `listen` is not expecting a first parameter of type `&WebServer`. You would need this signature:
`fn listen(f: fn(&WebServer, u32, u32) )`

Note that if hypothetically `listen` did have that signature, our program would work. See this last [playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=fn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20w%20=%20WebServer;%0A%20%20%20%20w.serve%28%29;%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20listen%28f:%20fn%28&WebServer,%20u32,%20u32%29%20%29%20%7B%20f%28&WebServer,%201,%202%29%20%7D%0A%0Astruct%20WebServer;%0Aimpl%20WebServer%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20serve%28&self%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20listen%28WebServer::return_page%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20return_page%28&self,%20a:%20u32,%20b:%20u32%29%20%7B%20println!%28%22%7B%7D,%20%7B%7D%22,%20a,%20b%29%20%7D%0A%7D) example

Comment: That definitely explains the problem.  Unfortunately, I'm not about to tinker with `listen`, since it's part of the `hyper` library.  And `return_page` needs access to member variables, so that's constrained, too.