# How do I access a struct field which has the same name as a public function?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to access the version of a particular `clap::App` I have instantiated.  However, the field [`version`](https://kbknapp.github.io/clap-rs/src/clap/app.rs.html#90) exists as does the public function [`version()`](https://kbknapp.github.io/clap-rs/src/clap/app.rs.html#299)

Here is the relevant bits of source code:

```
pub struct App<'a, 'v, 'ab, 'u, 'h, 'ar> {
    // ...
    version: Option<&'v str>,
    // ...
}

impl<'a, 'v, 'ab, 'u, 'h, 'ar> App<'a, 'v, 'ab, 'u, 'h, 'ar>{
    // ...
    pub fn version(mut self, v: &'v str) -> Self {
        self.version = Some(v);
        self
    }
    // ...
}
```

And my code:

```
pub fn build_cli() -> App<'static, 'static> {
    App::new("my-pi")
        .version("0.1.0")
// ...

let app = build_cli();
assert_eq!(app.version, "0.1.0"); // <-- Error here
```

The field `version` and function `version()` both exist on `App`.  How can this be? And how can I access the field `version`?

The error:

```
error[E0615]: attempted to take value of method `version` on type `clap::App<'_, '_>`
  --> src/cli.rs:27:21
   |
27 |         assert_eq!(app.version, "0.1.0");
   |                        ^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: maybe a `()` to call it is missing?
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How can this be?

The language is defined in such a way that there is no conflict between fields and methods.

> How can I access the field version?

You can't: it is private and does not have a getter method.

Answer (score 13):

You access a field that is named the same as a function by *accessing the field*:

```
struct Example {
    foo: i32,
}

impl Example {
    fn foo(&self) -> i32 {
        self.foo + 100
    }
}

fn main() {
    let ex = Example { foo: 42 };

    println!("{}", ex.foo);
    println!("{}", ex.foo());
}
```

It is assumed that, without the parenthesis, you want the field's value.

See also:

- [How do I call a function through a member variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27994509/155423)