# How can I store an async function in a struct and call it from a struct instance?

Tags: asynchronous, struct, rust, async-await, future

I'm trying to achieve this with the new `async`/`await` syntax, `std::future::Future`s and a recent version of Tokio. I'm using Tokio `0.2.0-alpha.4` and Rust `1.39.0-nightly`.

Different things I've tried include:

- using `Box<dyn>`s for the types that I want to store in the struct
- using generics in the struct definition

I couldn't quite get a minimal working version, so here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve:

```rust
async fn foo(x: u8) -> u8 {
    2 * x
}

// type StorableAsyncFn = Fn(u8) -> dyn Future<Output = u8>;

struct S {
    f: StorableAsyncFn,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>> {
    let s = S { f: foo };

    let out = (s.f)(1).await;

    Ok(())
}
```

Of course this code fails to compile with the following error:

```
error[E0412]: cannot find type `StorableAsyncFn` in this scope
```

`StorableAsyncFn` is not defined here, it's the type I'm trying to define.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Let's use this as our [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
async fn foo(x: u8) -> u8 {
    2 * x
}

struct S {
    foo: (),
}

async fn example() {
    let s = S { foo };
}
```

It produces the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:10:17
   |
10 |     let s = S { foo };
   |                 ^^^ expected (), found fn item
   |
   = note: expected type `()`
              found type `fn(u8) -> impl std::future::Future {foo}`
```

The type of `foo` is a function pointer that takes a `u8` and returns some type implementing the trait `std::future::Future`. `async fn` is effectively just syntax sugar that transforms `-> Foo` into `-> impl Future<Output = Foo>`.

We make our struct generic and place a trait bound on the generic that matches. In real code, you'd probably want to place a constraint on the the `Output` associated type, but it's not needed for this example. We can then call the function like any other callable member field:

```
async fn foo(x: u8) -> u8 {
    2 * x
}

struct S<F>
where
    F: std::future::Future,
{
    foo: fn(u8) -> F,
}

impl<F> S<F>
where
    F: std::future::Future,
{
    async fn do_thing(self) {
        (self.foo)(42).await;
    }
}

async fn example() {
    let s = S { foo };
    s.do_thing().await;
}
```

To be even more flexible, you could use another generic to store a closure, instead of forcing only a function pointer:

```
struct S<C, F>
where
    C: Fn(u8) -> F,
    F: std::future::Future,
{
    foo: C,
}

impl<C, F> S<C, F>
where
    C: Fn(u8) -> F,
    F: std::future::Future,
{
    async fn do_thing(self) {
        (self.foo)(42).await;
    }
}
```

See also:

- [How do I call a function through a member variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27994509/155423)
- [How do I store a closure in a struct in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27831944/155423)

Comment: Thanks for the super clear answer. Also, good to know you can have a generic parameter be a `Future` without specifying the `Output`.

Comment: Thanks for the great Demo!  ^_^ .. 
When a function need to return Vec<S>, how to specify the return type ?
Vec<S> is not working, it complains `Output ...`.  Could you have a return type example ?

Answer (score 18):

Another way to store an async function is with trait objects. This is useful if you want to be able to swap out the function dynamically at runtime, or store a collection of async functions. To do this, we can store a boxed `Fn` that returns a boxed `Future`:

```rust
use futures::future::BoxFuture; // Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = T> + Send>>

struct S {
    foo: Box<dyn Fn(u8) -> BoxFuture<'static, u8>,
}
```

However, if we try to initialize `S`, we immediately run into a problem:

```rust
async fn foo(x: u8) -> u8 {
    x * 2
}

let s = S { foo: Box::new(foo) };
```

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<fn(u8) -> impl futures::Future {foo} as FnOnce<(u8,)>>::Output == Pin<Box<(dyn futures::Future<Output = u8> + 'static)>>`
  --> src/lib.rs:14:22
   |
5  | async fn foo(x: u8) -> u8 {
   |                        -- the `Output` of this `async fn`'s found opaque type
...
14 |     let s = S { foo: Box::new(foo) };
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Pin`, found opaque type
   |
   = note: expected struct `Pin<Box<(dyn futures::Future<Output = u8> + 'static)>>`
           found opaque type `impl futures::Future`
```

The error message is pretty clear. `S` expects a owned `Future`, but `async` functions return `impl Future`. We need to update our function signature to match the stored trait object:

```rust
fn foo(x: u8) -> BoxFuture<'static, u8> {
    Box::pin(async { x * 2 })
}
```

That works, but it would be a pain to `Box::pin` in every single function we want to store. And what if we want to expose this to users?

We can abstract the boxing away by wrapping the function in a closure:

```rust
async fn foo(x: u8) -> u8 {
    x * 2
}

let s = S { foo: Box::new(move |x| Box::pin(foo(x))) };
(s.foo)(12).await // => 24
```

This works fine, but we can make it even nicer by writing a custom trait and performing the conversion automagically:

```rust
trait AsyncFn {
    fn call(&self, args: u8) -> BoxFuture<'static, u8>;
}
```

And implement it for the function type we want to store:

```rust
impl<T, F> AsyncFn for T
where
    T: Fn(u8) -> F,
    F: Future<Output = u8> + 'static,
{
    fn call(&self, args: u8) -> BoxFuture<'static, u8> {
        Box::pin(self(args))
    }
}
```

Now we can store a trait object of our custom trait!

```rust
struct S {
    foo: Box<dyn AsyncFn>,
}


let s = S { foo: Box::new(foo) };
s.foo.call(12).await // => 24
```

Comment: This answer inspired me to look up `BoxFuture` and solved my problem at hand. Thank you!

Comment: what if the args type is not `u8` but a `&mut u8` ?