# Could not store async function in a struct field in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a struct `Task` which is defined as below:

```rs
pub struct Task<F>
where
    F: Future<Output = ()>,
{
    pub name: &'static str,
    pub should_run_late: bool,
    pub time: Time,
    runner: fn() -> F,
}

impl<F> Task<F>
where
    F: Future<Output = ()>,
{
    pub async fn run(self) {
        (self.runner)().await;
    }

    pub fn set_Runner(&mut self, func: fn() -> F)
    {
        self.runner = func;
    }
}
```

and call it this way

```rs
tokio::spawn(async move {
    task.run().await;
});
```

I'm putting Tasks in a vector in some struct like this:

```rs
some struct {
    pub tasks: HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Vec<Task<dyn Future<Output = ()>>>>>
}
```

The problem is in the above which says it doesn't implement `Sized` trait and when then wrapped it with Box:

```rs
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Vec<Task<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()>>>>>>
```

It says to use Box::pin.
It really makes everything confusing.
I'm fairly new in rust, and what ever I try I can't make it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the type of the `F` parameter in the `Vec<Task<F>>` won't help, since as written, `F` must match the *actual return type of the `runner` function*. You need to handle the function “dynamically” too, not just the future. Once you do, the code can also be simplified. Here's a new definition of `Task`:

```rust
pub struct Task {
    pub name: &'static str,
    pub should_run_late: bool,
    pub time: Time,
    runner: Box<dyn FnOnce() -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + Send>> + Send>,
}
```

Notice that the stored function returns `Pin<Box<dyn Future>>`, so we need to wrap the function when it's stored by `set_runner`. (This is going to match the `Box::pin()` that you noticed being asked for.) Actually running the task is the same:

```rust
impl Task {
    pub async fn run(self) {
        (self.runner)().await;
    }

    pub fn set_runner<Func, Fut>(&mut self, func: Func)
    where
        Func: Send + 'static + FnOnce() -> Fut,
        Fut: Send + 'static + Future<Output = ()>,
    {
        self.runner = Box::new(move || Box::pin(func()));
    }
}
```

I generalized the `func` parameter so it will accept closures and not just function pointers — since we're boxing the function anyway, this is free.

[Compilable sample on Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b311bd256ba43aead78799467650c344)

---

Now, this code can be a bit messy to read. There are a couple of libraries providing trait aliases which can help you out by removing the boilerplate. The `futures` library contains [`futures::future::BoxFuture`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/type.BoxFuture.html) which tidies up storing a boxed future:

```rust
use futures::future::BoxFuture;

pub struct Task {
    ...
    runner: Box<dyn FnOnce() -> BoxFuture<'static, ()> + Send>,
}
```

For the input to `set_runner`, the two lines of trait bounds are just saying "`Func` is an async function which takes no arguments and returns `()`". We can simplify that (somewhat) using [`async_fn_traits`](https://docs.rs/async_fn_traits/):

```rust
use async_fn_traits::AsyncFnOnce0;

impl Task {
    ...
    pub fn set_runner<F>(&mut self, func: F)
    where
        F: AsyncFnOnce0<Output = ()> + Send + 'static,
        F::OutputFuture: Send + 'static,
    {
        self.runner = Box::new(move || Box::pin(func()));
    }
}
```

In situations that don't involve storing the future this would be even more of an improvement (because we would not need to write out the `Send + 'static` bounds), but at least here we avoid needing the separate `Fut` type parameter which can't actually vary independently.

Using these aliases is entirely optional — it's up to you which version of the code you think is clearer. For what it's worth, `futures` is quite commonly used for other future-related utilities, and `async_fn_traits` is considerably more obscure.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks for the demo.  Would you have a "function pointers" version example?  I think it would be simpler.

Comment: Can I use simpler type `my_func_field: Fn(u8) -> Future` ?
something from https://stackoverflow.com/a/58174632/5827450

Comment: @Charlie木匠 You cannot use a function pointer as the type of `self.runner` because you can't write a wrapper function for a function pointer that's also a function pointer.