# Store references to `async` functions

Tags: rust, rust-async-std

I want to store pointers to async functions in some static list and call them later.  How can I do this?  E.g.

```rust
//async
fn foo() {
}

//async
fn bar() {
}

type MyFn = fn();

const RUNNERS: &[MyFn] = &[
    foo,
    bar,
];

async fn run() {
    RUNNERS[0]()
    //RUNNERS[0]().await
}

fn main() {
    let _ = run();
}
```

is a working version for non-async functions.

How have I to implement this so that I can uncomment the `async` and `await` like in this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=abc17a578f7c10e4f11ab2f6c21eb2da) to a non-working version?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58173711/how-can-i-store-an-async-function-in-a-struct-and-call-it-from-a-struct-instance and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27994509/how-do-i-call-a-function-through-a-member-variable

Comment: @AlexanderBielby this does not really seems to apply; it is solved there by generics or boxes which does not work for the static `const RUNNER`

Comment: @ensc it is not currently possible, but you can use [lazy_static](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static) instead for similar results.