# Rust equivalent of c++'s std::bind

Tags: c++, rust

I currently have this issue where I have two structs, and one of the structs holds the other (example below). I want to be able to pass one of the methods of the outer struct to the inner struct, without the inner struct having a reference to the outer one. In c++ you could achieve this with std::bind, at least if I understand correctly. Below is the working c++ code. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

c++:

```
class first
{
public:
    first();
    void method(int number);
    int thenumber;
    second other;
};


first::first() {
    other = second(std::bind(&first::method, this, std::placeholders::_1));
}

void first::method(int number) {
    thenumber = number;
}

class second
{
public:
    second();
    second(std::function<void(int)> method);
    std::function<void(int)> func;
};


second::second() {
    
}

second::second(std::function<void(int)> method) {
    func = method;
}

int main() {
    auto test = new first();

    test->other.func(5);

    std::cout << test->thenumber;

    return 0;
}
```

Rust:

```
struct First {
    other: Second
}

struct Second {
    func: /* some kind of function reference */
}

// No clue how to do the struct implementations
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Rust equivalent of c++'s `std::bind` is a lambda function. BTW the shown C++ code is invalid: `second` is unknown identifier to `first`.

Comment: You can simply bind arguments through closure, no?

Comment: @freakish I could, but the function that changes the number needs two things: a self reference to access the struct field, and a number to set the struct field to. how do I get the self reference?

Comment: Does [How can I modify self in a closure called from a member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28597666/7582247) help?