# How do I store a list of callbacks on a struct?

Tags: rust

This is a follow-up to my question on [how to create & use a list of callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28956195/how-do-i-create-use-a-list-of-callback-functions).

I'm trying to create (and store, near an event loop) a list of callback functions that will be called at some indeterminate point in the future.

```
struct ComplexThing {
    calls: Vec<Box<FnMut()>>,
}


impl ComplexThing {
    fn call<'a, T: FnMut() + 'a>(&'a mut self, func: T) {
        self.calls.push(Box::new(func));
    }
}
```

Errors with:

```
calls.rs:30:25: 30:39 error: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough [E0310]
calls.rs:30         self.calls.push(Box::new(func));
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
calls.rs:30:39: 30:39 help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `T: 'static`...
calls.rs:30:25: 30:39 note: ...so that the type `T` will meet its required lifetime bounds
calls.rs:30         self.calls.push(Box::new(func));
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I tried adding it to the `struct`, which fixed the error about lifetimes on the call to `push`,

```
struct ComplexThing<'a> {
    calls: Vec<Box<FnMut() + 'a>>,
}


impl ComplexThing {
    fn call<'a, T: FnMut() + 'a>(&'a mut self, func: T) {
        self.calls.push(Box::new(func));
    }
}
```

… but gets me:

```
calls.rs:28:6: 28:18 error: wrong number of lifetime parameters: expected 1, found 0 [E0107]
calls.rs:28 impl ComplexThing {
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Which, yes, I suppose the struct has a `<'a>`, and I'm not specifying it. If I add it,

```
impl ComplexThing<'a> {
```

I get,

```
calls.rs:28:19: 28:21 error: use of undeclared lifetime name `'a` [E0261]
calls.rs:28 impl ComplexThing<'a> {
```

I don't know if I should be specifying it on the `struct ComplexThing` or not. If I leave it off (and I would greatly prefer to, I think),

I think there's something crucial about how Rust notates lifetimes that I'm not getting here. The `FnMut` that `ComplexThing` is (presently) trying to store in a `Box` is (in the design in my head) *owned* by the instance of `ComplexThing`; it's lifetime should be less than that of `.ComplexThing` — i.e., one of two things would happen:

1. What will be a private function of the `ComplexThing` will end up removing the `Box<FnMut>` from the `Vec` (and thus, take ownership of it), run the `FnMut`, and then exit, thus freeing the `FnMut`.
2. The `ComplexThing` is deallocated, in which case the `Vec` and any `Box<FnMut>`'s are deallocated with it.

The question ["How do I store a closure in Rust?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831944/how-do-i-store-a-closure-in-rust/27832320#27832320)'s answer made me think a `Box<FnMut>` wouldn't need lifetime annotations, but the answer I got on [how to create & use a list of callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28956195/how-do-i-create-use-a-list-of-callback-functions) makes me think I do.

My best guess is that `Box` is just storing a pointer to an object that I don't really own, and that I need to either create a copy of the `FnMut` on the heap, or move-construct one there, and then that copy is the one I can own. (Otherwise, if it's like a closure that's on the stack, I need to make sure that closure doesn't go out of scope before my `Box` does, which is why Rust is having me annotate lifetimes.)

Comment: `Box<Trait>` is sugar for `Box<Trait + 'static>`, which explains the first error completely. `&'a Trait` is sugar for `&'a (Trait + 'a)`, incidentally.

Answer (score 3):

`'a` on `ComplexThing` is a generic lifetime parameter and needs to be defined just as much as a generic type parameter. If you had a `struct Foo<T>`, you would not be able to write `impl Foo<T>` because there is no concrete type `T` in scope; if you want it to be generic, you need to define it, `impl<T> Foo<T>`. This allows you to write constraints too, such as `impl<T: Clone> Foo<T>` to implement methods on `Foo<T>` only where `T` is a type that implements `Clone`.

So then, the answer is simply that you need to define the lifetime `'a` as generic:

```rust
impl<'a> ComplexThing<'a> { … }
```