# The compiler suggests I add a 'static lifetime because the parameter type may not live long enough, but I don't think that's what I want

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to implement something that looks like this minimal example:

```
trait Bar<T> {}

struct Foo<T> {
    data: Vec<Box<Bar<T>>>,
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn add<U: Bar<T>>(&mut self, x: U) {
        self.data.push(Box::new(x));
    }
}
```

Since Rust defaults to (as far as I can tell) pass-by-ownership, my mental model thinks this should work.  The `add` method takes ownership of object `x` and is able to move this object into a `Box` because it knows the full type `U` (and not just trait `Bar<T>`).  Once moved into a `Box`, the lifetime of the item inside the box should be tied to the actual lifetime of the box (e.g., when `pop()`ed off the vector the object will be destroyed).

Clearly, however, the compiler disagrees (and I'm sure knows a bit more than I...), asking me to consider adding a `'static` lifetime qualifier (E0310).  I am 99% sure that's not what I want, but I'm not exactly sure what I'm supposed to do.

To clarify what I'm thinking and help identify misconceptions, my mental model, coming from a C++ background, is:

- `Box<T>` is essentially `std::unique_ptr<T>`
- Without any annotations, variables are passed by value if `Copy` and rvalue-reference otherwise
- With a reference annotation, `&` is roughly `const&` and `&mut` is roughly `&`
- The default lifetime is lexical scope

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Check out the entire error:

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `U` may not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:9:24
  |
8 |     fn add<U: Bar<T>>(&mut self, x: U) {
  |            -- help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `U: 'static`...
9 |         self.data.push(Box::new(x));
  |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
note: ...so that the type `U` will meet its required lifetime bounds
 --> src/main.rs:9:24
  |
9 |         self.data.push(Box::new(x));
  |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Specifically, the compiler is letting you know that it's possible that some arbitrary type `U` *might contain a reference*, and that reference could then become invalid:

```
impl<'a, T> Bar<T> for &'a str {}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo { data: vec![] };

    {
        let s = "oh no".to_string();
        foo.add(s.as_ref());
    }
}
```

That would be Bad News.

Whether you want a `'static` lifetime or a parameterized lifetime is up to your needs. The `'static` lifetime is easier to use, but has more restrictions. Because of this, it's the default when you declare a *trait object* in a struct or a type alias:

```
struct Foo<T> {
    data: Vec<Box<dyn Bar<T>>>,
    // same as
    // data: Vec<Box<dyn Bar<T> + 'static>>,
}
```

However, when used as an argument, a trait object uses *lifetime elision* and gets a unique lifetime:

```
fn foo(&self, x: Box<dyn Bar<T>>)
// same as
// fn foo<'a, 'b>(&'a self, x: Box<dyn Bar<T> + 'b>)
```

These two things need to match up.

```
struct Foo<'a, T> {
    data: Vec<Box<dyn Bar<T> + 'a>>,
}

impl<'a, T> Foo<'a, T> {
    fn add<U>(&mut self, x: U)
    where
        U: Bar<T> + 'a,
    {
        self.data.push(Box::new(x));
    }
}
```

**or**

```
struct Foo<T> {
    data: Vec<Box<dyn Bar<T>>>,
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn add<U>(&mut self, x: U)
    where
        U: Bar<T> + 'static,
    {
        self.data.push(Box::new(x));
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't express enough how valuable this explanation is. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 32):

> asking me to consider adding a 'static lifetime qualifier (E0310). I am 99% sure that's not what I want, but I'm not exactly sure what I'm supposed to do.

Yes it is. The compiler does not want a `&'static` reference, it wants `U: 'static`.

Having `U: 'static` means that `U` contains no references with a lifetime less than `'static`. This is required because you want to put a `U` instance in a structure without lifetimes.

```
trait Bar<T> {}

struct Foo<T> {
    data: Vec<Box<dyn Bar<T>>>,
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn add<U: Bar<T> + 'static>(&mut self, x: U) {
        self.data.push(Box::new(x));
    }
}
```