# Lifetime error on struct referring to a parametrized function

Tags: rust

If I write the code below, I get `error[E0309]: the parameter type 'T' may not live long enough`.

```
struct Function<T> {
    f: fn() -> T,
}

struct FunctionRef<'f, T> {
    f: &'f Function<T>,
}
```

This fixes the error:

```
struct FunctionRef<'f, T: 'f> {
    f: &'f Function<T>,
}
```

However, as far as I can tell, `T` is not bound on the lifetime `'f`. Indeed, `T` is a new object created when the function of type `fn () -> T` is run.

Where am I missing something?

Comment: This is effectively the same question as [The compiler suggests I add a 'static lifetime because the parameter type may not live long enough, but I don't think that's what I want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40053550/the-compiler-suggests-i-add-a-static-lifetime-because-the-parameter-type-may-no): `T: 'f` does not mean that *every* `T` lives for at least `'f`, it means that `T` cannot contain any references with a lifetime less than `'f`.

Comment: The only lifetime bound that makes sense here is using `T: 'static`. Since the function pointed to by `f` does not take any arguments, it can't really return a reference with any other lifetime than the static lifetime. (The situation would be different if you changed the type of `f` to a generic type `F: Fn() -> T`, since this would also allow for closures, which can return captured references that have different lifetimes.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: You need `T: 'f` because `T` may contains field that hold references and `fn() -> T` is covariant over `T`.

To simplify things may help to understand ...

For a moment substitute `fn() -> T` with `T`, because for me it is more simple to explain what it is happening with lifetimes.
See the Note below why with this substitution does not change the lifetime related error.

```
struct Function<T> {
    f: T,
}

struct FunctionRef<'f, T> {
    f: &'f Function<T>,
}
```

This lead to the same `error[E0309]: the parameter type 'T' may not live long enough` error.

`FunctionRef` instances cannot outlive the reference it holds in `f` field:
you declare a generic lifetime parameter `'f` inside angle brackets and then you use `'f` as an annotation
inside the struct body. See also the [book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-annotations-in-struct-definitions).

But `FunctionRef::f` depends on a type parameter `T`. The explicit constraint `T: 'f` guarantee that `T` instances
does not outlive references holded by `T` and  `FunctionRef` does not outlive `FunctionRef::f`.

If it can help to understand substitute the generic `T` with a specific `Foo` type:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    n: &'a i32,
}

struct FunctionRef<'f, 'a: 'f> {
    f: &'f Foo<'a>,
}
```

You need to constraint lifetime `'a` to be valid at least as long as `'f` lifetime, otherwise memory safety rules would be violated.

### Note

I have considered the case `f: T` equivalent of `f: fn() -> T` because such type constructor is covariant over `T`.

To grasp the meaning of `fn() -> T` is covariant over `T`, consider this struct:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    v: &'a i32
}
```

In this case is safe to assign to `v` a value with a lifetime "bigger" than `'a`, for example:

```
let ref_value: &'static i32 =  &100;
let foo = Foo { v: ref_value};
```

Now the same holds for the following struct:

```
struct Function<'a> {
    f: fn() -> &'a i32
}
```

The field `f` expects a function that returns a `&i32` that outlive `'a`.

In this case it is safe to pass a function that returns a `&i32` with a "bigger" lifetime, for example:

```
fn my_f() -> &'static i32 {
    &100
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Function { f: my_f};
}
```

There is quite a lot of type theory behind this, [see the nomicom](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html?highlight=constructor#variance) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you. I understand your statement and I agree with it. However it does not answer my question. In the case you are showing I agree that `T` should be live longer than the lifetime`'f`. However, I still do not understand why the statement "`T` should be live longer than the lifetime`'f" is true for the case I presented in my question.
You say "This error has nothing to do with the fact that Function::f is a function". To this I want to ask "Why?". Sorry if I am dumb.

Comment: I see your doubt, I've added a note.