# Why will a move closure not capture a value with a generic type?

Tags: generics, rust, closures, borrow-checker

I'm trying to create a ScopeRunner type that can store method calls to a method of types implementing the Scope trait like this:

```rust
trait Scope {
    fn run(&self) -> String;
}

struct ScopeImpl;

impl Scope for ScopeImpl {
    fn run(&self) -> String {
        "Some string".to_string()
    }
}


struct ScopeRunner {
    runner: Box<dyn Fn() -> String>,
}

impl ScopeRunner {
    fn new<S: Scope>(scope: S) -> Self {
        ScopeRunner {
            runner: Box::new(move || scope.run())
        }
    }

    pub fn run(self) -> String {
        (self.runner)()
    }

}


fn main() {
    let scope = ScopeImpl {};
    let scope_runner = ScopeRunner::new(scope);

    dbg!(scope_runner.run());
}
```

I would expect that since `ScopeRunner::new` creates a move closure this would cause scope to be moved into the closure. But instead the borrow checker gives me this error:

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `S` may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:21:30
   |
20 |     fn new<S: Scope>(scope: S) -> Self {
   |            -- help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `S: 'static`...
21 |         ScopeRunner {runner: Box::new(move || scope.run())}
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: ...so that the type `[closure@src/main.rs:21:39: 21:58 scope:S]` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/main.rs:21:30
   |
21 |         ScopeRunner {runner: Box::new(move || scope.run())}
   |
```

When I replace `ScopeRunner::new` with a non generic version that just takes a `ScopeImpl` this code does work.

```rust
fn new(scope: ScopeImpl) -> Self {
    ScopeRunner {
        runner: Box::new(move || scope.run())
    }
}
```

I don't understand why this is different. To me it seems the lifetime of the generic `Scope` would be the same as the concrete version.

Comment: After reading Peter Halls excellent answer and researching a bit more I realized my question might be a duplicate of this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40053550/the-compiler-suggests-i-add-a-static-lifetime-because-the-parameter-type-may-no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `S` could be any type with a `Scope` impl, which includes all kinds of not-yet-existing types that carry references to other types. For example you could have an implementation like this:

```
struct AnotherScope<'a> {
    reference: &'str,
}

impl Scope for ScopeImpl {
    fn run(&self) -> String {
        self.reference.to_string()
    }
}
```

Rust is cautious and wants to make sure that this will work for *any* qualifying `S`, including if it contains references.

The easiest fix is to do as the error note suggests and just disallow `S` from having any non-static references:

```
fn new<S: Scope + 'static>(scope: S) -> Self {
    ScopeRunner {
        runner: Box::new(move || scope.run())
    }
}
```

Bounding `S` with `'static` effectively means that `S` can contain either references to values with a `'static` lifetime or no references at all.

If you want to be a bit more flexible, you can broaden that to references that outlive the `ScopeRunner` itself:

```
struct ScopeRunner<'s> {
    runner: Box<dyn Fn() -> String + 's>,
}

impl<'s> ScopeRunner<'s> {
    fn new<S: Scope + 's>(scope: S) -> Self {
        ScopeRunner { 
            runner: Box::new(move || scope.run())
        }
    }

    pub fn run(self) -> String {
        (self.runner)()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems bounding S with 'static like the compiler suggests means something different here than I was expecting. This is going to be part of the public interface of my cmdr crate and I was hoping to avoid forcing users to specify lifetimes, as Scope will be implemented by them but I don't think I can avoid it here.

Comment: @Mendelt Users of your API still shouldn't need to write explicit lifetimes most of the time.