# Why is a lifetime bound required on a generic return type of a boxed trait object closure?

Tags: generics, rust, traits, lifetime, box

I'm having an issue with the compiler complaining that `Box<dyn 'f + FnMut(A)>` does not implement `'f + FnMut(A)` if `A` isn't bound to the lifetime `'t`. I've reduced it to this minimal example, where `FnMut(A)` is replaced by `Foo<A>`:

```rust
trait Foo<A> {}
impl<'a, A> Foo<A> for &'a () {}
impl<'a, A> Foo<A> for Box<dyn 'a + Foo<A>> {}

fn through_box<'a, A>(x: &'a ()) -> impl 'a + Foo<A>
where
    //A: 'static,
{
    let box_: Box<dyn 'a + Foo<A>> = Box::new(x);
    box_
}
```

```
error[E0309]: the parameter type `A` may not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:5:37
  |
5 | fn through_box<'a, A>(x: &'a ()) -> impl 'a + Foo<A>
  |                    -                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |                    |
  |                    help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `A: 'a`...
  |
note: ...so that the type `std::boxed::Box<dyn Foo<A>>` will meet its required lifetime bounds
 --> src/main.rs:5:37
  |
5 | fn through_box<'a, A>(x: &'a ()) -> impl 'a + Foo<A>
  |                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This does not compile while it does by uncommenting the lifetime constraint on `A`.

The following also compiles:

```rust
trait Foo {}
impl<'a> Foo for &'a () {}
impl<'a> Foo for Box<dyn 'a + Foo> {}

fn through_box<'a>(x: &'a ()) -> impl 'a + Foo {
    let box_: Box<dyn 'a + Foo> = Box::new(x);
    box_
}
```

I do not understand why the first program requires that bound on `A`.

Note that my issue is not boxing the function in a `Box<dyn 'a + Foo<A>>`, which does work, but the fact that this `Box<dyn 'a + Foo<A>>` seems to be itself not of lifetime `'a`, hence the error on the return type and not when initializing `box_`.

Comment: Your question may be answered by the answers of [The compiler suggests I add a 'static lifetime because the parameter type may not live long enough, but I don't think that's what I want](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40053550/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.