# Can 'static be placed along the struct declaration?

Tags: syntax, rust, lifetime

In Rust programming language, can there be a case where `'static` is placed here:

```
struct Abc <'static> {
  ...
```

Comment: What indicates it might? Have you tried it?

Comment: I don't think so. The lifetime there is to have a lifetime available sort of as a variable that you can attach to inner fields. But you could do `struct Abc<'a>` and initialize it statically.

Comment: @underscore_d I tried. I didn't manage to do it which doesnt mean it cannot be placed in certain circumstances.

Comment: "_I didn't manage to do it_" Why not? What error did the compiler report?

Comment: @underscore_d "^^^^^^^ 'static is a reserved lifetime name". But even if you put <'a> without using it is a compiler error, saying it is unused though.

Comment: What should this mean? You can already put `'static` inside non-generic structs, and you can parametrize generic structs with `'static` explicitly. How would this be different from either of those?

Comment: The motivation for the question comes from `impl Abc<'static> {` which I think is valid.

Comment: I guess I don't really understand the question. At first I thought you had some idea what `struct Abc<'static> {` would mean if it were allowed, and were asking about that. But it seems you're just asking if the syntax is allowed -- which you answered for yourself: no, `'static` is a reserved lifetime name, you can't use it as the name of a lifetime parameter. So what *is* the question?

Comment: Exactly that is my original question and the answer which is satisfying. I didn't answer myself. I couldn't find a construct that would allow `struct Abc<'static>{`, but I didn't prove there cannot be any such.

Comment: Does one of the existing posts satisfy your question, or are you hoping for something else?

Comment: Both satisfy. I will select one as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Every type has an implicit `'static` lifetime if no generic lifetime is specified. Lifetimes in the declaration of a structure as in

```rust
struct Abc<'here, 'and, 'there>;
```

are meant to specify that the structure contains shorter lifetimes and give them a name. `'static` being a special lifetime doesn't need to be specified here or to have a local name.

This doesn't mean however that those lifetimes can't be `'static` for a particular instance of the structure.

Comment: `Everything has an implicit 'static lifetime by default if no other lifetime is specified.` That would imply that `&self` in `fn anymethod(&self, ...) -> ... { ... }` has `'static` lifetime, which is simply not true... Lifetime is inferred from context. Rust doesn't assume that it is just `'static`. When it cannot infer, in cases such as struct declarations or specific function declarations, then you have to add it yourself.

Comment: @Sahsahae mcarton is correct: if a concrete type has no lifetime parameters, the type is `'static`. This is not the same as saying that *references* to the type must be `'static`. `String`, for example, is a type with no lifetime parameters, and `String: 'static`, even though `&String` need not be.

Comment: Read, for example, the answers to [The compiler suggests I add a 'static lifetime because the parameter type may not live long enough, but I don't think that's what I want](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40053550/3650362).

Comment: I think the way @trentcl rephrased it is less ambiguous. Thanks @trentcl!

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit like asking if can you specify `i32` as a type parameter in a struct declaration:

```
struct Abc<i32> {}
```

It doesn't make sense<sub>[1]</sub>.

A type parameter lets fields of a struct be generic:

```
struct Abc<T> {
    foo: T, // a user of this struct can choose the type of T
}
```

In the same way, a lifetime parameter allows the lifetime of a reference to be generic:

```
struct Abc<'a> {
    foo: &'a str, // a user of this struct can choose the lifetime bound
}
```

If you want the lifetime to be always static, then just specify that, rather than making it generic:

```
struct Abc {
    foo: &'static str, // this must always be static
}
```

---

<sub>[1] Actually it declares a type parameter, which just happens to have the same name as the `i32` type—but that is unlikely to be what a person who tried writing something like this would have intended.</sub>