# Lifetime error when making parameter generic

Tags: rust

I've reduced my problem to the following code:

```
struct Struct<'a, 'b, T> {
    a: &'a T,
    b: &'b T,
}

trait Trait<'a, 'b, T> {
    fn a(&self) -> &'a T;
    fn b(&self) -> &'b T;
}

impl<'a, 'b, T> Trait<'a, 'b, T> for Struct<'a, 'b, T> {
    fn a(&self) -> &'a T {
        self.a
    }
    fn b(&self) -> &'b T {
        self.b
    }
}

struct Confused<T> {
    field: T,
}

impl<T> Confused<T> {
    fn foo<'a, 'b>(&'a self, param: &Struct<'a, 'b, T>) -> &'a T {
        param.b();
        param.a()
    }

    fn bar<'a, 'b, U: Trait<'a, 'b, T>>(&'a self, param: &U) -> &'a T {
        param.b();
        param.a()
    }
}
```

The function `foo` is okay, but when I replace the concrete type `Struct<'a, 'b, T>` with a generic type `U: Trait<'a, 'b, T>`, I get the following error:

> ```
> error[E0309]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
>   --> src/lib.rs:31:15
>    |
> 24 | impl<T> Confused<T> {
>    |      - help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `T: 'b`...
> ...
> 31 |         param.b();
>    |               ^
>    |
> note: ...so that the reference type `&'b T` does not outlive the data it points at
>   --> src/lib.rs:31:15
>    |
> 31 |         param.b();
>    |               ^
> ```

The suggestion to add the bound `T: 'b` doesn't make sense to me, since `'b` is a parameter to `bar()`.  How can I fix `bar()` to accept any implementation of `Trait<'a, 'b, T>` as a parameter?

Comment: What is your **question**? You've only stated facts so far.

Comment: I have added my question explicitly

Comment: You state that the bound the compiler suggests doesn't make sense to you, but what prevents you from adding it anyway, even though you don't understand it?

Comment: Adding `'b` as a lifetime parameter to `Confused` changes the meaning of the code.  `foo()` and `bar()` are generic over both lifetimes.  Why is that okay for `foo()` but not `bar()`?

Comment: Why would you add the constraint to `Confused` instead of to `bar`?

Comment: See also [The compiler suggests I add a 'static lifetime because the parameter type may not live long enough, but I don't think that's what I want](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40053550/155423)

Comment: Ah, because `T` is not a parameter to `bar()` and I didn't realize I could add constraints anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write a generic type such as:

```
struct Foo<'a, T> {
    a: &'a T,
}
```

Rust automatically adds an implicit restriction of the type `T: 'a`, because your reference to `T` cannot live longer than `T` itself. This is automatic because your type would not work without it.

But when you do something like:

```
impl<T> Foo {
    fn bar<'a, 'b>() -> &'a T {/*...*/}
}
```

there is an automatic `T: 'a` but not a `T: 'b` because there is no `&'b T` anywhere.

The solution is to add those constraints by yourself. In your code it would be something like this:

```
impl<T> Confused<T> {
    fn bar<'a, 'b, U: Trait<'a, 'b, T>>(&'a self, param: &U) -> &'a T
    where
        T: 'b, //<--- here!
    {
        param.b();
        param.a()
    }
}
```

Comment: So for `foo()`, the `T: 'b` constraint is implied by `Struct<'a, 'b, T>`.  But the same doesn't happen for `U: Trait<'a, 'b, T>`, even though it would be impossible to implement that trait if that bound did not hold.

Comment: @TavianBarnes: Yes, I think it is exactly that. The funny thing is that you cannot implement `Trait<`a, `b, T>` unless `T: 'a + 'b`, but you can _use_ the `Trait<`a, `b, T>` even though `T: !'b` as long as you do not call `Trait::b`. In your original code, if you remove the call to `param.b()` it will compile just fine.

Comment: It looks like this might be fixed by https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2089 which is not yet implemented.

Comment: @TavianBarnes: I don't think this change applies to your code. Note that any automatic requirement added to your original code would be a breaking change, as currently your code would compile without the `param.b()`, but adding a `T: 'b` automaticall would break it.

Comment: What would the added implied bound break exactly?  Just `{ param.a() }` would continue to compile, and my existing code would unbreak.  There can't be any callers of `bar()` that would be broken by the new bound since all instances of `Trait` satisfy it already.

Comment: @TavianBarnes: Hmmm, you may be right. I was thinking that if you remove the `param.b()` your code will compile and the `'b` will be unconstrained. A generic user of this function could call it with a different `'b`, and that user could break with the automatic constraint. But since this latter generic would be uninstantiable anyway... maybe it doesn't matter and should fail earlier.

Comment: It now occurs to me that just having an impl of that trait around *doesn't* imply `T: 'b`, because the impl could just `panic!()` or otherwise diverge.  It's only safe to assume `T: 'b` after the method returns.

Comment: OTOH, if I wrote `trait Trait<'a, 'b, T> where T: 'b`, implied bounds would do what I expected