# Cast Arc<RwLock<T>> to Arc<RwLock<TraitObject>

Tags: generics, rust, clone, traits, trait-objects

I am writing a graph implementation with edges and nodes. The graph should be accessed concurrently so I chose to build the Edges and Nodes as `Arc<Mutex<dyn Edge>>` and `Arc<RwLock<dyn Node>>`.

Unfortunately I get a compile error `the parameter type 'T' may not live long enough` ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5010f4c9801c5c2e43317d051fcfbd2d)) when connecting nodes/edges.

```
pub trait Node {
  fn connect(&mut self, edge: EdgeRef);
}

pub type NodeRef = Arc<RwLock<dyn Node>>;

pub trait Edge {
  fn connect(&mut self, node: NodeRef);
}

pub type EdgeRef = Arc<Mutex<dyn Edge>>;

impl<T> Node for Arc<RwLock<T>>
where
  T: Node,
{
  fn connect(&mut self, edge_ref: EdgeRef) {
    let mut node = self.write().unwrap();
    let mut edge = edge_ref.lock().unwrap();
    let self_clone = self.clone() as NodeRef; // the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
    edge.connect(self_clone);
    node.connect(edge_ref.clone());
  }
}
```

The problem is: An `Arc<RwLock<T>>` should is not a reference so there should be no lifetime. Casting it to `Arc<RwLock<dyn Node>>` also does not introduce lifetimes.

Can someone explain this compiler error? Is this problem related to every parametric type (e.g. `Type<T>`) or only to `Arc<RwLock<T>>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compile error explains how to fix the problem:

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:22:22
   |
15 | impl<T> Node for Arc<RwLock<T>>
   |      - help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `T: 'static`
...
22 |     let self_clone = self.clone() as NodeRef;
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: ...so that the type `T` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/lib.rs:22:22
   |
22 |     let self_clone = self.clone() as NodeRef;
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0310`.
```

Adding `+ 'static` to your `T`'s bounds does indeed fix the error:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, RwLock};

pub trait Node {
  fn connect(&mut self, edge: EdgeRef);
}

pub type NodeRef = Arc<RwLock<dyn Node>>;

pub trait Edge {
  fn connect(&mut self, node: NodeRef);
}

pub type EdgeRef = Arc<Mutex<dyn Edge>>;

impl<T> Node for Arc<RwLock<T>>
where
  T: Node + 'static, // added "+ 'static" here
{
  fn connect(&mut self, edge_ref: EdgeRef) {
    let mut node = self.write().unwrap();
    let mut edge = edge_ref.lock().unwrap();
    let self_clone = self.clone() as NodeRef;
    edge.connect(self_clone);
    node.connect(edge_ref.clone());
  }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7faeb5664a31b775e7767ede984e5be6)

*But why do I need a lifetime bound when my T will never be a reference?* you ask. Well, the Rust compiler doesn't know that yet, a `T` can be any type, including references. The set of types represented by `T` includes the set of types represented by `&T` and `&mut T`. Both `&T` and `&mut T` are subsets of `T`. That's why you have to put a lifetime bound on `T`, it's your way of communicating to the compiler that your `T` will only be owned types or static references.

**More on 'static lifetimes**

`'static` is a misleading name for the lifetime because it causes most people to think `'static` types have to live for the entire duration of the program and cannot be dynamically allocated or dropped. Neither of these are true in reality: `'static` types can be dynamically allocated and they also can be dropped. What `'static` really means in practice is *"you can safely hold on to this type indefinitely"*. All "owned types" like `String` and `Vec` are `'static`. Here's a Rust program which I hope illustrates this point:

```
use rand::prelude::*; // 0.7.3

// this function takes 'static types and drops them
// no compiler errors because 'static types can be dynamically allocated and dropped
fn is_static<T: 'static>(t: T) {
    std::mem::drop(t)
}

fn main() {
    let string = String::from("string"); // dynamically allocated string
    is_static(string); // compiles just fine

    let mut strings: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    let mut loops = 10;
    while loops > 0 {
        if rand::random() {
            strings.push(format!("randomly dynamically allocated string on loop {}", loops));
        }
        loops -= 1;
    }

    // all the strings are 'static
    for string in strings {
        is_static(string); // compiles no problem
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e7e733927d4059de9a94d7dab7f7d218)

**More on lifetime elision and default trait object lifetimes**

You define `NodeRef` and `EdgeRef` as such:

```
pub type NodeRef = Arc<RwLock<dyn Node>>;
pub type EdgeRef = Arc<Mutex<dyn Edge>>;
```

However the Rust compiler interprets those like so:

```
pub type NodeRef = Arc<RwLock<dyn Node + 'static>>;
pub type EdgeRef = Arc<Mutex<dyn Edge + 'static>>;
```

So when you want to cast some `Arc<RwLock<T>>` to `NodeRef` then `T` must be bounded by `Node + 'static` because `NodeRef` also has those bounds, i.e. `Arc<RwLock<dyn Node + 'static>>`. All trait objects in Rust have lifetimes, but you don't usually write them since Rust infers them for you. [The Rust Reference has a thorough explanation on lifetime elision and default trait object lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html) if you'd like to learn more.

You can ease the `'static` requirement by making your type aliases generic over `'a`:

```
pub type NodeRef<'a> = Arc<RwLock<dyn Node + 'a>>;
pub type EdgeRef<'a> = Arc<Mutex<dyn Edge + 'a>>;
```

However that will dramatically increase the complexity of your code and I'm pretty sure you want to stick with `'static` as it already supports what you're trying to do.

Comment: Maybe my understanding of `'static` is wrong (I added my understanding to the upper post). If this is so, can you explain to me why nodes that get added (or removed) later on can have a `'static` lifetime?

Comment: @CoronA I've updated my answer above, please let me know if it helps, thanks.

Comment: Maybe it is a step in the right direction. But I do not understand why the lifetime is a problem: The argument `Arc<RwLock<T>>` ensures that `T` lives at least as long as Arc, so casting to `Arc<RwLock<dyn Node>>>` should infer this lifetime for the trait object (for every lifetime). Is this idea wrong or is the compiler not as clever?

Comment: @CoronA if you remove the `as NodeRef` cast you will still get the same compiler error about `T` not living long enough. The issue has nothing to do with casting an `Arc<RwLock<T>>` to a `Arc<RwLock<dyn Node>>>`. [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d13ec50f03b456c530645b3f1a8ad632)

Comment: There is an implicit cast in `edge.connect(self_clone);`. Replace this line with `self.clone().connect(edge_ref.clone());`, it compiles (it is endless recursion, so only build it). For me, is seems that casting to the trait object is the problem. [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3e69dfbccfa4965b0ff2c69a002e9131)

Comment: @CoronA I've updated my answer again, please let me know if it helps, thanks.

Comment: That answers my question. The link an trait object default lifetimes was very helpful. I am just curious where the meaning of `'static` (as constraint of generic type parameters) is documented officially. Although your description proved right, I did not find another resource confirming it explicitly.

Comment: I found a confirming explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40053550/the-compiler-suggests-i-add-a-static-lifetime-because-the-parameter-type-may-no).

Answer (score 2):

The type `Arc<RwLock<T>>` could *potentially* be a reference.  Since it is a generic and `T` is not yet defined.  When you attempt to use it with `dyn` then `T` becomes a reference, though not quite the same as a normal reference.

Rust By Example has a simple explanation [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/trait/dyn.html)

To solve this you could change `T: Node,` to `T: Node + 'static` as the compiler may suggest or you could wrap your `dyn Node` in a [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html).

Comment: From my point of view the `T` could not be `'static` when such nodes could be added interactively to the graph (maybe my point of view is wrong). About the hint with `RefCell` - is there a difference to `RwLock`?

Comment: RwLock allows you to explicitly specify when a thread is using data.  All checks are made during compilation.  RefCell does something similar, but does it at runtime.  Though it _does_ means you have a little more cpu overhead while running.
Check [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html) out for a lot more info.

Comment: My question was not for the general difference - I asked whether this would change anything considering the lifetimes. Probably not. On `RwLock` and `RefCell`: Look [here](https://ricardomartins.cc/2016/06/25/interior-mutability-thread-safety), I think both do runtime checks.