# Why does an Iterator trait object referring to a sibling field fail to compile when the concrete type works?

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

I'd like to have an iterator that points into a `Vec` of the same struct.

The following works fine ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6bf8f37fa174b1f84d6a0f5ad9e37bb2)):

```rust
struct Holder1<'a> {
    vec: Vec<i32>,
    iterator: Option<Box<std::slice::Iter<'a, i32>>>,
}

fn holder1_test() {
    let vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    let mut holder = Holder1 {
        vec,
        iterator: None,
    };
    let iterator: Box<std::slice::Iter<'_, i32>> = Box::new(holder.vec.iter());
    holder.iterator = Some(iterator);

    for iter_elem in holder.iterator.as_mut().unwrap() {
        println!("iter: {}", iter_elem);
    }
}
```

(I know the `Box` isn't needed here, I just wanted to keep this as close as possible to the next code snippet.)

I'd like to use a trait object, `dyn Iterator`, instead of the concrete type. I've slightly modified the example from above for that ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d7a42009b17c3854d9d398aca30f66a7)):

```rust
struct Holder2<'a> {
    vec: Vec<i32>,
    iterator: Option<Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'a i32>>>,
}

fn holder2_test() {
    let vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    let mut holder = Holder2 {
        vec,
        iterator: None,
    };
    let iterator: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'_ i32>> = Box::new(holder.vec.iter());
    holder.iterator = Some(iterator);

    for iter_elem in holder.iterator.as_mut().unwrap() {
        println!("iter: {}", iter_elem);
    }
}
```

This fails to compile:

```
error[E0597]: `holder.vec` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:12:64
   |
12 |     let iterator: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'_ i32>> = Box::new(holder.vec.iter());
   |                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
18 | }
   | -
   | |
   | `holder.vec` dropped here while still borrowed
   | borrow might be used here, when `holder` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `Holder2<'_>`
```

What makes the second example so different to the first example that causes the compilation failure? Both iterators point to an element in the `Vec` of the same struct - so what's the conceptual difference here? Is there a way to get this to work with trait objects?

I'm aware that using an index instead of an iterator would solve this, but I'm rather interested in the underlying reasons of why this doesn't work.

Comment: See also [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423); [The compiler suggests I add a 'static lifetime because the parameter type may not live long enough, but I don't think that's what I want](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40053550/155423).

Comment: 97% this has something to do with drop glue. Since `slice::Iter` doesn't have any, the compiler can shorten the borrow lifetime, but `Box<dyn Iterator...>` can't make that assumption. Anyway, you should probably just use indices (if you need to store the iterator in the struct at all).