# What should be the lifetime restrictions of a Trait parameter that is moved into a filter closure?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have two methods on a struct.

The first method is a search which expects a criteria, and will return an iterator that applies that criteria:

```
pub fn search<'s>(
    &'s self,
    criteria: impl Criteria + 's,
) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'s Record> + 's {
    self.records.iter().filter(move |&tr| criteria.apply(tr))
}
```

I will admit to being a little confused as to why `criteria` has to have an explicit lifetime, because I move ownership of `criteria` into the `filter` closure. I would imagine it becomes owned by the `Iterator`, and thus have the same lifetime.

But, it works. Then I add on this function:

```
pub fn search_sorted<C, CMP>(&self, criteria: C, compare: CMP) -> Vec<(&UniqueId, &T)>
where
    C: Criteria,
    CMP: FnMut(&(&UniqueId, &T), &(&UniqueId, &T)) -> Ordering,
{
    let search_iter = self.search(criteria);
    let mut records: Vec<(&UniqueId, &T)> = search_iter.collect();
    records.sort_by(compare);
    records
}
```

Here the compiler insists that I need a lifetime on `criteria`. This confuses me, because `criteria` is an owned parameter, and then I'm passing ownership on to `self.search`. When I try to take the advice of the compiler to add a lifetime annotation, the compiler then just asks for more.

Here's a complete example that I built in Rust Playground:

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;

struct Record {}

trait Criteria {
    fn apply(&self, r: &Record) -> bool;
}

struct List {
    records: Vec<Record>
}

impl List {    
    fn new(lst: Vec<Record>) -> List {
        List{ records: lst }
    }
    
    pub fn search<'s>(
        &'s self,
        criteria: impl Criteria + 's,
    ) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'s Record> + 's {
        self.records.iter().filter(move |&tr| criteria.apply(tr))
    }
    
    pub fn search_sorted<C, CMP>(&self, criteria: C, compare: CMP) -> Vec<&Record>
    where
        C: Criteria,
        CMP: FnMut(&&Record, &&Record) -> Ordering,
    {
        let search_iter = self.search(criteria);
        let mut records: Vec<&Record> = search_iter.collect();
        records.sort_by(compare);
        records
    }

}
```

And then the error that I get (much forshortened) is this:

```
error[E0311]: the parameter type `C` may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:30:32
   |
25 |     pub fn search_sorted<C, CMP>(&self, criteria: C, compare: CMP) -> Vec<&Record>
   |                          - help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `C: 'a`
...
30 |         let search_iter = self.search(criteria);
   |                                ^^^^^^
   |
note: the parameter type `C` must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 25:5...
  --> src/lib.rs:25:5
```

Can you give any advice for resolving this? For me, the obvious solution would just be "callers are required to do their own sorting", and I won't rule that out, but I do like having this utility function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I will admit to being a little confused as to why `criteria` has to have an explicit lifetime, because I move ownership of `criteria` into the filter closure.

From the function's perspective, `Criteria` is a trait, that could have any number of implementations and any of those implementations might contain references. This annotation makes sure that, *if* the implementation of `Criteria` *does* contain a reference, its lifetime must be longer than the call to `search`. Otherwise it can't guarantee that an arbitrary criteria is valid throughout the body of the function.

The same is also true for `search_sorted`. You just need to add the lifetime parameter, as the error message suggested:

```
pub fn search_sorted<'s, C, CMP>(&'s self, criteria: C, compare: CMP) -> Vec<&Record>
where
    C: Criteria + 's,
    CMP: FnMut(&&Record, &&Record) -> Ordering,
{
    let search_iter = self.search(criteria);
    let mut records: Vec<&Record> = search_iter.collect();
    records.sort_by(compare);
    records
}
```

Note that I've also constrained `&self` with the same lifetime. This is the connection that allows the compiler to guarantee that the criteria does not contain references with a lifetime shorter than the function body. This in turn allows the compiler to guarantee that it can guarantee the lifetime requirements of `search` when it is called by `search_sorted`.

Comment: Egads. I was sure I had done exactly that, but it seems that I missed some aspect of the lifetime when I was trying things. Must have been `&'s self` on `search_sorted`. Thank you. Instant resolve.

Comment: Commenting solely to link to [The compiler suggests I add a 'static lifetime because the parameter type may not live long enough, but I don't think that's what I want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40053550/the-compiler-suggests-i-add-a-static-lifetime-because-the-parameter-type-may-no) which is the other, albeit less general way to solve this (make `C: 'static`).

Comment: I've now had a lot more hours to think about this, and the entire concept that the trait implementation might contain references is something that escaped me. It's a really helpful point.