# Argument requires that value is borrowed for `'static` not working for non copy value

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, reference-counting

The below code doesn't work because the argument to `thread::spawn` requires that `some` is borrowed for `'static`, I get it:

```
fn main() {
    let some = "Some".to_string();
    let apple = Arc::new(&some);

    for _ in 0..10 {
        let apple = apple.clone();

        thread::spawn(move || {
            println!("{:?}", apple);
        });
    }
}
```

But how come the following works? Since `String` is not `Copy`, how come this doesn't also cause the borrowed value to not live long enough? Is the `String` becoming static to adjust for the thread code?

```
fn main() {
    let some = "Some".to_string();
    let apple = Arc::new(some);

    for _ in 0..10 {
        let apple = apple.clone();

        thread::spawn(move || {
            println!("{:?}", apple);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `String` is `'static`, which is not the same as saying that `some` is static. See [The compiler suggests I add a 'static lifetime because the parameter type may not live long enough, but I don't think that's what I want](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40053550/3650362)

Comment: you're creating an Arc to a reference, and the referenced doesn't live past main. I can't see a use case for using an Arc to a reference, arc is itself a reference to its contained object after all. Generally you want to give ownership of the variable to the Arc ( 2nd snippet ). Thus instead of having the string living just through main, it lives as long as all the clones of the arc lives.

Comment: @vincent thanks for the answer.Also for guiding why it's not a good idea to use Arc to a ref

Answer (score 4):

Quoting the [`Arc` docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html)

> The type `Arc<T>` provides shared ownership of a value of type `T`, allocated in the heap. Invoking `clone` on `Arc` produces a new `Arc` instance, which points to the same allocation on the heap as the source `Arc`, while increasing a reference count. When the last `Arc` pointer to a given allocation is destroyed, the value stored in that allocation (often referred to as “inner value”) is also dropped.
>
> Shared references in Rust disallow mutation by default, and `Arc` is no exception: you cannot generally obtain a mutable reference to something inside an `Arc`. If you need to mutate through an `Arc`, use `Mutex`, `RwLock`, or one of the `Atomic` types.

TL;DR: `Arc` takes ownership of the passed value.

If the value is a reference, obviously only this reference is shared, not the actual data. Because you are moving the `Arc` (or its clones) to other threads, Rust cannot know how long it will live and therefore requires the contained data to be `'static`.

Answer (score 1):

To keep it simple you could think of an `Arc` as keeping the value it contains alive while it or any of its clones are alive.

In your first example the contained value is the reference of some.
But references may only live as long as what they borrow from.
Therefor the borrow may only be kept alive by the Arc's for the lifetime of `some` and this means the Arc's themselves may only be kept alive for the same lifetime as otherwise they would keep the borrow alive for too long.
This conflicts with the requirement of `std::thread::spawn`.

In your second example the contained value is the actual String value of `some` that is moved into the Arc. Now there is no borrowing constrained as the Arc actually owns the String and can keep it alive as long as it or any of its clones live.
Therefor the Arc can be kept alive for the `'static` lifetime if necessary as
it can in turn keep the String alive.
This means `std::thread::spawn`s requirement is fulfilled as the cloned Arc can be kept alive for long enough.