# How to return an anonymous type from a trait method without using Box?

Tags: rust

I have an extension trait whose methods are just shorthands for adapters/combinators:

```
fn foo(self) -> ... { self.map(|i| i * 2).foo().bar() }
```

The return type of `Trait::foo()` is some nested `Map<Foo<Bar<Filter...`, including closures, and is therefor anonymous for all practical purposes. My problem is how to return such a type from a trait method, preferably without using `Box`.

- `impl Trait` in return position would be the way to go, yet this feature is not implemented for trait methods yet.
- Returning a `Box<Trait>`is possible, yet I don't want to allocate for every adapter shorthanded by the trait.
- I can't put the anonymous type into a struct and return that, because `struct Foo<T> { inner: T }` can't be implemented (I promise an impl for all `T`, yet only return a specific `Foo<Map<Filter<Bar...`).
- Existential types would probably solve the above problem, yet they won't be implemented for some time.

I could also just avoid the problem and use a macro or a freestanding function; this also feels unhygienic, though.

Any more insights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[What is the correct way to return an Iterator (or any other trait)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423) covers all the present solutions. The one you haven't used is to replace closures with function pointers and then use a type alias (optionally wrapping in a newtype). This isn't always possible, but since you didn't provide a [MCVE](/help/mcve) of your code, we can't tell if this will work for you or not:

```
use std::iter;

type Thing<T> = iter::Map<iter::Filter<T, fn(&i32) -> bool>, fn(i32) -> i32>;

trait IterExt: Iterator<Item = i32> {
    fn thing(self) -> Thing<Self>
    where
        Self: Sized + 'static,
    {
        // self.filter(|&v| v > 10).map(|v| v * 2)
        fn a(v: &i32) -> bool { *v > 10 }
        fn b(v: i32) -> i32 { v * 2 }
        self.filter(a as fn(&i32) -> bool).map(b as fn(i32) -> i32)
    }
}

impl<I> IterExt for I
where
    I: Iterator<Item = i32>,
{}

fn main() {}
```

---

Honestly, in these cases I would create a newtype wrapping the boxed trait object. That way, I have the flexibility to internally re-implement it with a non-boxed option in an API-compatible fashion when it becomes practical to do so.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about fn-pointers and type aliases, seems like a lot of typing though. I was hoping for a magic wand of some kind. Here is playground with a slightly large example: The `ChildStatusBound`-Trait can be applied to any `futures::Stream`, yet needs boxing as of now. https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=365e732ec2177781901a6f89562865fe&version=stable

Comment: What is "newtype"?

Comment: @hippietrail https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#using-the-newtype-pattern-for-type-safety-and-abstraction