# Why does passing a closure to function which accepts a function pointer not work?

Tags: rust

In the [second edition of *The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-05-advanced-functions-and-closures.html) (emphasis mine):

> Function pointers implement all three of the closure traits (`Fn`, `FnMut`, and `FnOnce`), **so you can always pass a function pointer as an argument for a function that expects a closure**. It’s best to write functions using a generic type and one of the closure traits so your functions can accept either functions or closures.

Passing a closure to a function which accepts a function pointer as an argument doesn't compile:

```
fn main() {
    let a = String::from("abc");

    let x = || println!("{}", a);

    fn wrap(c: fn() -> ()) -> () {
        c()
    }

    wrap(x);
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:10:10
   |
10 |     wrap(x);
   |          ^ expected fn pointer, found closure
   |
   = note: expected type `fn()`
              found type `[closure@src/main.rs:4:13: 4:33 a:_]`
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: Please specify your actual question. (Do you want to know whether it is possible in general, or do you want to have docs why this does not work?)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

A closure isn't a function.

You can pass a function to a function expecting a closure, but there's no reason for the reverse to be true.

If you want to be able to pass both closures and functions as argument, just prepare it for closures.

For example:

```
let a = String::from("abc");

let x = || println!("x {}", a);

fn y() {
    println!("y")
}

fn wrap(c: impl Fn()) {
    c()
}

wrap(x); // pass a closure
wrap(y); // pass a function
```

Comment: Note: in Rust 2018, you need to write `&dyn Fn() -> ()` or `&impl Fn() -> ()`.

Comment: No, you don't **need** to do that, but you can. https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ad8cae9dfda6281e579f286300e597ed&version=beta&mode=debug&edition=2018 Do you have a link, that says anything else?

Comment: @hellow my understanding is that the distinction should now be explicit and the implicit notation is or will be deprecated

Comment: Should, then. I was under the impression that this kind of syntax-breaking change is exactly why the edition was made, but perhaps this was seen as too abrupt.

Comment: @DenysSéguret the book says **you can always pass a function pointer as an argument for a function that expects a closure**

Comment: @周汉成 yes, but you were trying the reverse, which isn't possible.

Comment: @DenysSéguret yeah..that expression is fuzzy. It's better to say **you can always pass a function as an argument for a function that expects a closure**, or assuming that's right: **you can always pass a function pointer as an argument type for a function that expects a closure**

Comment: I tried `&Fn ..`, `&impl Fn ..` and `&dyn Fn ..` All works. So what is the difference between them?

Comment: @Nawaz `&Fn` is a shortcut for `&dyn Fn` which is a dynamic dispatch (lighter in memory but slower).

Comment: @DenysSéguret: And `&impl Fn` is static dispatch, I suppose? Can I use it without the `&`? Would that work? If not, **why**?

Comment: Taking a reference to the closure argument is pretty unusual. Normally this would be written as `fn wrap(c: impl Fn())`.

Answer (score 31):

There are certain cases where you **can** pass a closure as a function pointer. This works:

```
fn main() {
    let x = || {
        let a = String::from("abc");
        println!("{}", a);
    };

    fn wrap(c: fn()) {
        c()
    }

    wrap(x);
}
```

The important difference is that the closure is not allowed to capture *anything* from its environment. That means that we had to prevent the `String` from crossing the closure boundary.

Any closure that doesn't capture environment can be trivially rewritten as a anonymous standalone function and then converted into a function pointer.

Once you add an environment, it is no longer convertible and everything from [the existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52697820/155423) applies.

Note that stating `-> ()` is non-idiomatic as that's the default if nothing is specified.

See also:

- [RFC 1558 - Closure to `fn` Coercion](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1558-closure-to-fn-coercion.md)

Comment: Can you really call it a closure if it doesn't close over anything ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret a tricky semantics question! I think you are right that technically it's not a closure, but it is using the closure *syntax*. Most programmers are OK with ignoring these specific details, letting the compiler figure out the best implementation.

Comment: Just like C++! ;-)

Comment: @DenysSéguret a closure closes over a set of objects, the empty set is a valid set.