# Can Rust cast between function types when I don't care about some of the arguments?

Tags: rust

I have 3 function types:

```rust
type ThreadedFunction = fn(&mut Thread, Object) -> FunctionResult;
type UniversalFunction = fn(&mut Thread, Unused) -> FunctionResult;
type Function = fn(&mut Thread, &Method) -> FunctionResult;
static_assertions::assert_eq_size!(primitives::Unused, &Method);
static_assertions::assert_eq_size!(primitives::Unused, Object);
```

The universal functions ignore the second parameter, so I'd like to be able to use them in the two other contexts. The sizes of `Object`, `Unused` and `&Method` are the same.

I would like to be able to do something like:

```rust
pub fn unused(thread: &mut Thread, _: Unused) -> FunctionResult {
    NormalReturn
}

pub fn somewhere() -> ThreadedFunction {
    unused as ThreadedFunction
}
```

This is unsafe:

```
error[E0605]: non-primitive cast: `for<'r> fn(&'r mut interpreter::Thread, interpreter::primitives::Unused) -> interpreter::FunctionResult {unused}` as `for<'r> fn(&'r mut interpreter::Thread, object::Object) -> interpreter::FunctionResult`
  --> src/interpreter.rs:25:13
   |
25 |             unused as ThreadedFunction
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ invalid cast
```

Wrapping the cast in `unsafe {}` doesn't help.

This could be impossible, but it would be very convenient to be able to do as it would save a bunch of code duplication.

Comment: By definition, those aren't compatible because they have different types...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot perform this cast because the function references have different types. All of the parameter types and return types must be the same for two functions to have the same type.

Instead, you can return a closure that doesn't capture any environment. Because of that, it can be automatically converted into a function:

```rust
fn somewhere() -> ThreadedFunction {
    |a, b| unused(a, Unused)
}
```

That is equivalent to this wrapper function:

```rust
fn unused_adapted(thread: &mut Thread, _: Object) -> FunctionResult {
    unused(thread, Unused)
}

fn somewhere() -> ThreadedFunction {
    unused_adapted
}
```

See also:

- [Why does passing a closure to function which accepts a function pointer not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52703106/155423)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. And with aggressive inlining there wouldn't be much downside.