# Different but similar ways of creating a hashmap

Tags: rust

The following code shows some ways of creating a HashMap.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let h1 : HashMap<usize, (fn(usize) -> usize, usize, usize)> = HashMap::new();
    h1.insert(1, (|n| n, 1, 1)); // works fine
    let h2 : HashMap<usize, (fn(usize) -> usize, usize, usize)> = HashMap::from([(1, (|n| n, 1, 1))]); // error
    HashMap::<usize, (fn(usize) -> usize, usize, usize)>::from([(1, (|n| n, 1, 1))]); // error
}
```

These seems to essentially express the same thing, but the Rust compiler disagrees ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=19ca664823f328c6326a6aa8319a086a))!

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:23:67
   |
23 |     let h2 : HashMap<usize, (fn(usize) -> usize, usize, usize)> = HashMap::from([(1, (|n| n, 1, 1))]);
   |              --------------------------------------------------   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected fn pointer, found closure
   |              |
   |              expected due to this
   |
   = note: expected struct `HashMap<usize, (fn(usize) -> usize, usize, usize)>`
              found struct `HashMap<{integer}, ([closure@src/main.rs:23:87: 23:92], {integer}, {integer})>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `HashMap<usize, (fn(usize) -> usize, usize, usize)>: From<[({integer}, ([closure@src/main.rs:24:70: 24:75], {integer}, {integer})); 1]>` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:24:5
    |
24  |     HashMap::<usize, (fn(usize) -> usize, usize, usize)>::from([(1, (|n| n, 1, 1))]);
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<[({integer}, ([closure@src/main.rs:24:70: 24:75], {integer}, {integer})); 1]>` is not implemented for `HashMap<usize, (fn(usize) -> usize, usize, usize)>`
    |
    = help: the following implementations were found:
              <HashMap<K, V> as From<[(K, V); N]>>
note: required by `from`
```

Why do I get these errors for way 2 and 3, but not for the first way?

Comment: For some reason I am not currently able to explain, the Rust compiler is not implicitly casting the closure type in the last two cases to a fn pointer type. Such implicit cast does indeed occur in the first case. You may suppress the error with an explicit cast such as `(|n| n) as _`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fn(usize) -> usize` is a function pointer and `|n| n` is a closure. Closures that don't capture environment variables can be automatically converted to function pointers, which happens in this line

```
h1.insert(1, (|n| n, 1, 1));
```

More information about the distinction between function pointers and closures can be found [in this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52696907/why-does-passing-a-closure-to-function-which-accepts-a-function-pointer-not-work)

For some reason, the automatic conversion is not applied in the second and third cases but the compiler can be coerced into doing so by typing `(|n| n) as _` or `(|n| n) as fn(usize) -> usize`.

If you want to store closures that capture variables (instead of function pointers), you have to put them in a `Box` similar to this:

```rust
let some = "hello".to_string();
let mut h1 : HashMap<usize, Box<dyn Fn(usize) -> usize>> = HashMap::new();
h1.insert(1, Box::new(move |_n| some.len())); // 'some' is moved here
```