# Initialize method pointer inside struct

Tags: pointers, rust, emulation

I am trying to write a NES emulator.

I have created a lookup table that contains all the instructions for the 6502. Each Instruction contains the name of the instruction, a pointer to the method that is the instruction, a pointer to the address mode method, and how many cycles the instruction takes.

These are the structures for the CPU (Nes6502) and a structure for what each Instruction contains.

```rust
pub struct Nes6502 {
    bus: Bus,

    /// Accumulator Register
    a: u8,
    /// X Register
    x: u8,
    /// Y Register
    y: u8,
    /// Stack pointer (pointers to a location on the bus)
    stkp: u8,
    /// Program counter
    pc: u16,
    /// Status Register
    status: u8,
    fetched: u8,
    addr_abs: u16,
    addr_rel: u16,
    opcode: u8,
    cycles: u8,
    lookup: Vec<Instruction>,
}

struct Instruction {
    name: String,
    operate: fn() -> u8,
    addrmode: fn() -> u8,
    cycles: u8,
}
```

But the issue I run into is when I try to initialize the lookup table for the instructions

```rust
impl Nes6502 {
    fn new() -> Nes6502 {
        let mut ram= [0; MEM_SIZE]; 
        ram.iter_mut().for_each(|r| *r = 0x00);

        let mut nes = Nes6502 { 
            a: 0x00,
            x: 0x00,
            y: 0x00,
            stkp: 0x00,
            pc: 0x0000,
            status: 0x00,
            fetched: 0x00,
            addr_abs: 0x0000,
            addr_rel: 0x00,
            opcode: 0x00,
            cycles: 0,
            lookup: Vec::new(),

            bus: Bus {
                ram
            }   
        };

        nes.lookup = vec![
            Instruction{ name: String::from("BRK"), operate: || nes.BRK(), addrmode: || nes.IMM(), cycles: 7 } // ...
        ]
    
        nes
    }
    // ...
}
```

In the part where I initialize the lookup table with all the instructions I get this error

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/nes_6502.rs:86:63
   |
86 | ...   Instruction{ name: String::from("BRK"), operate: || nes.BRK(), addrmode: || nes.IMM(), cycles: 7 }// ,Instruction{ name: String::fr...
   |                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected fn pointer, found closure
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `fn() -> u8`
                 found closure `[closure@src/nes_6502.rs:86:63: 86:75]`
note: closures can only be coerced to `fn` types if they do not capture any variables
  --> src/nes_6502.rs:86:66
   |
86 | ...   Instruction{ name: String::from("BRK"), operate: || nes.BRK(), addrmode: || nes.IMM(), cycles: 7 }// ,Instruction{ name: String::fr...
   |                                                           ^^^ `nes` captured here
```

I also tried initializing it like this

```
nes.lookup = vec![
            Instruction{ name: String::from("BRK"), operate: nes.BRK, addrmode: nes.IMM, cycles: 7 }
           ]
```

But that gave me this error

```
error[E0615]: attempted to take value of method `BRK` on type `Nes6502`
  --> src/nes_6502.rs:86:67
   |
86 | ...   Instruction{ name: String::from("BRK"), operate: nes.BRK, addrmode: nes.IMM, cycles: 7 }// ,Instruction{ name: String::from("ORA"),...
   |                                                            ^^^ method, not a field
   |
help: use parentheses to call the method
   |
86 |              Instruction{ name: String::from("BRK"), operate: nes.BRK(), addrmode: nes.IMM, cycles: 7 }
```

Comment: Please post the full error from `cargo check`, not your IDE.

Comment: In Rust, you almost never want `fn`. You want the traits `Fn`, `FnMut`, or `FnOnce`. That being said, in your case, even with those traits, you're trying to mutably borrow the `NES` struct twice at once, which Rust is not going to be happy with. If you want to go with this structure, you'll need to wrap your data in a `RefCell` or something that allows internal mutability (and very carefully do so)

Comment: It's better to just pass the instance to the functions as a parameter, then you can even use `fn` pointers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does passing a closure to function which accepts a function pointer not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52696907/why-does-passing-a-closure-to-function-which-accepts-a-function-pointer-not-work)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that answers my question, but I have asked this in a few places and got lots of different responses and to be honest I am very confused, would you mind sharing a code example of what you recommend I should do?

Comment: Basically, declare `operate: fn (&mut Nes6502) -> u8` and initialize your lookup table with `operate: |&nes| nes.BRK()` and the same for `addrmode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is your 'minimal' example, as your code doesn't reproduce your issue directly:

```rust
struct Bus {
    ram: [i32; 1024],
}

pub struct Nes6502 {
    bus: Bus,

    /// Accumulator Register
    a: u8,
    /// X Register
    x: u8,
    /// Y Register
    y: u8,
    /// Stack pointer (pointers to a location on the bus)
    stkp: u8,
    /// Program counter
    pc: u16,
    /// Status Register
    status: u8,
    fetched: u8,
    addr_abs: u16,
    addr_rel: u16,
    opcode: u8,
    cycles: u8,
    lookup: Vec<Instruction>,
}

struct Instruction {
    name: String,
    operate: fn() -> u8,
    addrmode: fn() -> u8,
    cycles: u8,
}

const MEM_SIZE: usize = 1024;

impl Nes6502 {
    fn new() -> Nes6502 {
        let mut ram = [0; MEM_SIZE];
        ram.iter_mut().for_each(|r| *r = 0x00);

        let mut nes = Nes6502 {
            a: 0x00,
            x: 0x00,
            y: 0x00,
            stkp: 0x00,
            pc: 0x0000,
            status: 0x00,
            fetched: 0x00,
            addr_abs: 0x0000,
            addr_rel: 0x00,
            opcode: 0x00,
            cycles: 0,
            lookup: Vec::new(),

            bus: Bus { ram },
        };

        nes.lookup = vec![
            Instruction {
                name: String::from("BRK"),
                operate: || nes.BRK(),
                addrmode: || nes.IMM(),
                cycles: 7,
            }, // ...
        ];

        nes
    }

    fn BRK(&self) -> u8 {
        todo!()
    }
    fn IMM(&self) -> u8 {
        todo!()
    }
    // ...
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:62:26
   |
62 |                 operate: || nes.BRK(),
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected fn pointer, found closure
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `fn() -> u8`
                 found closure `[closure@src/lib.rs:62:26: 62:38]`
note: closures can only be coerced to `fn` types if they do not capture any variables
  --> src/lib.rs:62:29
   |
62 |                 operate: || nes.BRK(),
   |                             ^^^ `nes` captured here

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:63:27
   |
63 |                 addrmode: || nes.IMM(),
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected fn pointer, found closure
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `fn() -> u8`
                 found closure `[closure@src/lib.rs:63:27: 63:39]`
note: closures can only be coerced to `fn` types if they do not capture any variables
  --> src/lib.rs:63:30
   |
63 |                 addrmode: || nes.IMM(),
   |                              ^^^ `nes` captured here
```

### `fn` vs `Fn`/`FnMut`/`FnOnce`

- `fn` is a function pointer. It is simply an address that points to some executable function. No data can be attached to an `fn`.
- `FnOnce` is a trait that describes some object that can be executed at least once. The object gets consumed in the process of executing it.
- `FnMut` is a trait that describes some object that can be executed multiple times, but either has a side effect or changes its internal state in the process. Mutable access to the object is required to execute it. Every `FnMut` is also `FnOnce`.
- `Fn` is a trait that describes some object that can be executed many times without side effects or internal state changes. A simple immutable reference is required to execute it. Every `Fn` is also `FnMut` and `FnOnce`.

`Fn`, `FnMut` and `FnOnce` are all based on actual objects in memory, and not just pointers. Therefore those can carry data.

#### Why is this important for your case?

`|| nes.BRK()` is a closure that takes no argument, but uses the `nes` object. Therefore it needs to store the reference to the `nes` object somewhere.

So the first intuition would be to change `fn` to `Box<dyn Fn>`, like this:

```rust
struct Bus {
    ram: [i32; 1024],
}

pub struct Nes6502 {
    bus: Bus,

    /// Accumulator Register
    a: u8,
    /// X Register
    x: u8,
    /// Y Register
    y: u8,
    /// Stack pointer (pointers to a location on the bus)
    stkp: u8,
    /// Program counter
    pc: u16,
    /// Status Register
    status: u8,
    fetched: u8,
    addr_abs: u16,
    addr_rel: u16,
    opcode: u8,
    cycles: u8,
    lookup: Vec<Instruction>,
}

struct Instruction {
    name: String,
    operate: Box<dyn Fn() -> u8>,
    addrmode: Box<dyn Fn() -> u8>,
    cycles: u8,
}

const MEM_SIZE: usize = 1024;

impl Nes6502 {
    fn new() -> Nes6502 {
        let mut ram = [0; MEM_SIZE];
        ram.iter_mut().for_each(|r| *r = 0x00);

        let mut nes = Nes6502 {
            a: 0x00,
            x: 0x00,
            y: 0x00,
            stkp: 0x00,
            pc: 0x0000,
            status: 0x00,
            fetched: 0x00,
            addr_abs: 0x0000,
            addr_rel: 0x00,
            opcode: 0x00,
            cycles: 0,
            lookup: Vec::new(),

            bus: Bus { ram },
        };

        nes.lookup = vec![
            Instruction {
                name: String::from("BRK"),
                operate: Box::new(|| nes.BRK()),
                addrmode: Box::new(|| nes.IMM()),
                cycles: 7,
            }, // ...
        ];

        nes
    }

    fn BRK(&self) -> u8 {
        todo!()
    }
    fn IMM(&self) -> u8 {
        todo!()
    }
    // ...
}
```

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `nes.lookup` because it is borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:59:9
   |
59 |         nes.lookup = vec![
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `nes.lookup` occurs here
...
62 |                 operate: Box::new(|| nes.BRK()),
   |                          ----------------------
   |                          |        |  |
   |                          |        |  borrow occurs due to use in closure
   |                          |        borrow of `nes.lookup` occurs here
   |                          cast requires that `nes` is borrowed for `'static`

error[E0597]: `nes` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:62:38
   |
62 |                 operate: Box::new(|| nes.BRK()),
   |                          ------------^^^-------
   |                          |        |  |
   |                          |        |  borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                          |        value captured here
   |                          cast requires that `nes` is borrowed for `'static`
...
69 |     }
   |     - `nes` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0597]: `nes` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:63:39
   |
63 |                 addrmode: Box::new(|| nes.IMM()),
   |                           ------------^^^-------
   |                           |        |  |
   |                           |        |  borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                           |        value captured here
   |                           cast requires that `nes` is borrowed for `'static`
...
69 |     }
   |     - `nes` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0505]: cannot move out of `nes` because it is borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:68:9
   |
62 |                 operate: Box::new(|| nes.BRK()),
   |                          ----------------------
   |                          |        |  |
   |                          |        |  borrow occurs due to use in closure
   |                          |        borrow of `nes` occurs here
   |                          cast requires that `nes` is borrowed for `'static`
...
68 |         nes
   |         ^^^ move out of `nes` occurs here
```

This brings us to the next problem though: The closure outlives the current function, and therefore the compiler cannot guarantee that the `nes` object lives longer than the closure. Further, for as long as the closure borrows the `nes` object, no mutable reference to the `nes` can exist, which is probably not what you want. I'm sure you want to modify the `nes` object.

So what you *really* want is to only borrow the `nes` object while **executing** the closure. This can be achieved by passing the `nes` object into the closure as a function argument.

Once we have done that, the closure now no longer stores any references or objects, and we can use a plain `fn` function pointer again:

```rust
struct Bus {
    ram: [i32; 1024],
}

pub struct Nes6502 {
    bus: Bus,

    /// Accumulator Register
    a: u8,
    /// X Register
    x: u8,
    /// Y Register
    y: u8,
    /// Stack pointer (pointers to a location on the bus)
    stkp: u8,
    /// Program counter
    pc: u16,
    /// Status Register
    status: u8,
    fetched: u8,
    addr_abs: u16,
    addr_rel: u16,
    opcode: u8,
    cycles: u8,
    lookup: Vec<Instruction>,
}

struct Instruction {
    name: String,
    operate: fn(&mut Nes6502) -> u8,
    addrmode: fn(&Nes6502) -> u8,
    cycles: u8,
}

const MEM_SIZE: usize = 1024;

impl Nes6502 {
    fn new() -> Nes6502 {
        let mut ram = [0; MEM_SIZE];
        ram.iter_mut().for_each(|r| *r = 0x00);

        let mut nes = Nes6502 {
            a: 0x00,
            x: 0x00,
            y: 0x00,
            stkp: 0x00,
            pc: 0x0000,
            status: 0x00,
            fetched: 0x00,
            addr_abs: 0x0000,
            addr_rel: 0x00,
            opcode: 0x00,
            cycles: 0,
            lookup: Vec::new(),

            bus: Bus { ram },
        };

        nes.lookup = vec![
            Instruction {
                name: String::from("BRK"),
                operate: |nes| nes.BRK(),
                addrmode: |nes| nes.IMM(),
                cycles: 7,
            }, // ...
        ];

        nes
    }

    fn BRK(&self) -> u8 {
        todo!()
    }
    fn IMM(&self) -> u8 {
        todo!()
    }
    // ...
}
```

---

#### Another minor nitpick

The name of your `Instruction` is most likely already known at compile time, so it saves time and resources to use `&'static str` instead:

```rust
struct Instruction {
    name: &'static str,
    operate: fn(&mut Nes6502) -> u8,
    addrmode: fn(&Nes6502) -> u8,
    cycles: u8,
}

// ...

        nes.lookup = vec![
            Instruction {
                name: "BRK",
                operate: |nes| nes.BRK(),
                addrmode: |nes| nes.IMM(),
                cycles: 7,
            }, // ...
        ];

// ...
```