# How to store a hyper::server::Server as a field in a struct?

Tags: rust, hyper

I have a library which uses hyper internally. I want the user to be able to create an `App`which contains a `Server` internally that handles HTTP connections.

```rust
use hyper::server::conn::AddrIncoming;
use hyper::server::Server;
use hyper::service::service_fn_ok;
use std::net::SocketAddr;

pub struct App {
    inner: Server<AddrIncoming, ()>,
}

impl App {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let addr = SocketAddr::from(([0, 0, 0, 0], 3000));
        let inner = Server::bind(&addr).serve(|| service_fn_ok(|_req| unimplemented!()));

        App { inner }
    }
}
```

([Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3e38863abe9f31dacf0ae064e9db2085))

The error is, as expected:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:15:15
   |
15 |         App { inner }
   |               ^^^^^ expected (), found closure
   |
   = note: expected type `hyper::server::Server<_, ()>`
              found type `hyper::server::Server<_, [closure@src/lib.rs:13:47: 13:88]>`
```

It's not well documented, but the second type parameter for `Server` is the kind of `MakeService` it uses.

I can't figure out how to refer to the closure in the type of `inner`. Is there some way that I can box the closure to make the code compile? Is there a way to implement `MakeService` by hand, instead of using a closure?

The hyper docs refer to the function `make_service_fn`, which returns a `MakeServiceFn`, but the type isn't public, so I can't use it in the type of `inner`.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How do I store a closure in a struct in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27831944/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: TL;DR the duplicate: yes, box the closure, or the thing containing the closure, and create a boxed trait object.

Comment: I understand how boxed trait objects work in general, I'm not sure how to apply them to the problem I have. What type should the boxed closure have? Specifically, what return type?

Comment: @muskox Did you sort this out? I have the same question.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is due to a type mismatch. In Rust, a type parameter is part of the type of a struct, so the type parameters for the server in your struct must match the ones you defined in your struct. In your case they don't.

There are 2 solutions to your problem.

## Add a type parameter for the second server parameter to your struct

```rust
pub struct App<T> {
    inner: Server<AddrIncoming, T>,
}
```

Now you'll be able to create apps with different types for the second type parameter of the server

## Find the type of the second argument of the server that you are creating

In your case, the type of the second argument is ``, so you would declare your struct like this:

```rust
type Service = ?; // This is really hard to find in this case.
pub struct App {
    inner: Server<AddrIncoming, Service>,
}
```

### Conclusion

In your case, I would recommend the first one because the type of the second type parameter of `Server` is hard to find and could very well change during the development of your program, so it's much easier to just have a type parameter on your struct.

However, sometimes you won't be able to use certain method on your server if you don't know that its type parameters don't implement certain traits, so you can add these traits to your type parameter like this:

```rust
pub struct App<T: Service> {
    inner: Server<AddrIncoming, T>,
}
```

It is recommended not to put the type parameters on the struct itself and to only put them on the `impl` blocks:

```rust
pub struct App<T> {
    inner: Server<AddrIncoming, T>,
}

impl App<T: Service> {
   // Here you'll be able to use the method from Server where T has to be a Service.
}
```

You can also do the same for functions like this:

```rust
pub struct App<T> {
    inner: Server<AddrIncoming, T>,
}

fn some_function(app: App<T: Service>) {
   // Here you'll be able to use the method from Server where T has to be a Service
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! [Adding a type parameter doesn't work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cdd2c8af1e1c442688fc677c7e90ba9f) because my app is not generic for different types, it uses a specific type. Finding the type of the `MakeService` is precisely what I'm having trouble with, it's a closure that returns a type that's private to `hyper`.