# Arc<Mutex<dyn FnOnce(A) -> A>> for closure in Rust

Tags: rust

I want to create a structure that has a field `mut_f` that contains mutable thread safe function(closure) that type is `A -> A`

For the initialization, the value is `identity` closure.

```
let identity = |a| a;

struct Foo<A> {
    mut_f: Arc<Mutex<dyn FnOnce(A) -> A>> 
}

let foo = Foo {
    mut_f: identity //error
};
```

This obviously has the error:

> let identity = |a| a; mismatched types
>
> expected struct `std::sync::Arc`, found closure
>
> note: expected struct `std::sync::Arc<std::sync::Mutex<(dyn std::ops::FnOnce(_) -> _ + 'static)>>`
> found closure `[closure@src/main.rs:36:20: 36:25]` help: use parentheses to call this closure: `(a)`rustc(E0308) main.rs(36, 20):
> the found closure main.rs(44, 17): expected struct `std::sync::Arc`,
> found closure No quick fixes available

and basically, I want to keep the closure definition as simple as possible because later I need to compose another functions(closures) in function composition manner.

So my question is what is the adequate/smart way to **Cast** closures to the `Arc<Mutex<dyn FnOnce(A) -> A>>` type?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831944/how-do-i-store-a-closure-in-a-struct-in-rust answer your question? (the accepted answer has an example of a boxed closure)

Comment: Actually yes and I've seen the answer, but did not noticed `Arc::new(Mutex::new(identity))` is the exact answer, so if you post the answer, I will accept that. The credit is yours. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Foo` is expecting a `Arc<Mutex<dyn FnOnce>>`, so if you pass just a closure you'll get that error. You can get around that by constructing the Arc and Mutex:

```rust
let foo = Foo {
    mut_f: Arc::new(Mutex::new(identity))
};
```