# How to define function that returns Struct<Fn>

Tags: function, rust, generic-type-argument

I have a struct

```
struct A<F: Fn(i32)->i32>
```

How to define function which return it like

```
fn some_function() -> A<Fn(i32)->i32>
```

?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I store a closure in a struct in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831944/how-do-i-store-a-closure-in-a-struct-in-rust)

Comment: You are aware that `Fn(i32) -> i32` is a trait, not a type, right?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the `fn` type instead of the `Fn` trait:

```rust
struct A(fn(i32) -> i32);

fn some_function() -> A {
    let square = |x| x * x;
    A(square)
}

fn main() {
    let f = some_function();
    println!("{}", f.0(7));
}
```

```
49
```

---

You can of course also use the `Fn` trait, but then you need to use the `impl` keyword:

```rust
struct A<T: Fn(i32) -> i32>(T);

fn some_function() -> A<impl Fn(i32) -> i32> {
    let square = |x| x * x;
    A(square)
}

fn main() {
    let f = some_function();
    println!("{}", f.0(7));
}
```

```
49
```

`impl` here means "this is a type that I don't want to write here completely, but believe me, it implements `Fn(i32) -> i32`".