# Pass a function to an object as creation parameter

Tags: rust

I am creating an object of `tesla`, that comes from the struct of `Car`.

The way each car gets energy to work is different, in the case of a Tesla, we plug in a cable and pass electricity, in the case of a Honda, we insert oil into a tank. I want my car struct to have a property of `get_energy` with a `Fn` datatype, so that when I create a new car I can pass in a function that will be called when I call `tesla.get_energy()`... the creation of tesla would ideally be something like `let tesla = Car(get_energy: || => {grab_cable(), insert_cable(), pass_electricty()})` which would look different from the creation of a Honda. Can I somehow do that?

Comment: With my minimal Rust knowledge, it seems like that would work. What errors do you get when you try doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the love of god I hope I'm not answering an undergrad's homework.

But assuming good faith, this is my approach. I would probably store that function/closure and box it. It will look like this.

```rust
struct Foo {
    pub foo: Box<dyn Fn(usize) -> usize>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn new(foo: impl Fn(usize) -> usize + 'static) -> Self {
        Self { foo: Box::new(foo) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo {
        foo: Box::new(|a| a + 1),
    };
    (foo.foo)(42);
    
    (Foo::new(|a| a + 1).foo)(42);
}
```

I of course stole it from here [How do I store a closure in a struct in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831944/how-do-i-store-a-closure-in-a-struct-in-rust). Not going to flag the question yet because I'm not used to stackoverflow.

Comment: awesome, thanks! No, I am not in undergrad :P

Comment: In the struuct you define that the is one uszie parameter and one only, what if I want my objects being created to have more, less, or different parameters... i.e., my Honda might need an oil type to be passed in while the Tesla should not.

Comment: might want to look at generics