# How do I return a boxed closure from a method that has a reference to the struct?

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime

I have a structure that contains a value and I want to obtain a function that operates on this value:

```
struct Returner {
    val: i32,
}

impl<'a> Returner {
    fn get(&'a self) -> Box<Fn(i32) -> i32> {
        Box::new(|x| x + self.val)
    }
}
```

This fails compilation:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
 --> src/main.rs:7:18
  |
7 |         Box::new(|x| x + self.val)
  |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 5:1...
 --> src/main.rs:5:1
  |
5 | impl<'a> Returner {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  = note: ...so that the types are compatible:
          expected &&Returner
             found &&'a Returner
  = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
  = note: ...so that the expression is assignable:
          expected std::boxed::Box<std::ops::Fn(i32) -> i32 + 'static>
             found std::boxed::Box<std::ops::Fn(i32) -> i32>
```

This is because the closure borrows `self`, which is fine by me, because I don't intend to use the obtained function after the struct is destroyed. From what I've gathered so far, there's two ways to make it possible:

1. Use the `move` keyword. I don't want to use it because it will take ownership on the object, and want I to use it after it has returned this function.
2. Explicitly specify the lifetime of the closure to tell the compiler that it has the same lifetime as the struct it was called from.

I think that 2 is the correct way in my situation, but I've not been able to find out how to specify the closure's lifetime. Is there a direct way to do it or I've got it all wrong and it contradicts Rust lifetime logic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, you can specify the lifetime of a boxed trait object by writing `Box<Trait + 'a>` and analogously for trait objects behind other kinds of pointers (if it's omitted, it defaults to `'static` at least in the case of `Box`). So in this specific case you want the return type `Box<(Fn(i32) -> i32) + 'a>`.

However, when you do that you will see another error about `self` not living long enough. The reason is that (without `move`) the closure will capture *a reference to the local variable `self`*. The solution is to use `move`. This does not move the `Returner` object, it moves `self` which is a *reference* to the `Returner` object.

In summary:

```
struct Returner {
    val: i32,
}

impl<'a> Returner {
    fn get(&'a self) -> Box<Fn(i32) -> i32 + 'a> {
        Box::new(move |x| x + self.val)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it me or this `<'a>` should be adorn `get` and not `impl`?

Comment: @MatthieuM. You're right, it should. It happens to not make a difference here because the `'a` doesn't occur anywhere else, but it's really the wrong place for the quantifier.

Comment: @ Matthieu M. I've checked both ways, the results are the same.

Answer (score 3):

As said [in an existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40544225/155423):

1. Add a lifetime that ties the lifetime of `self` to the lifetime of the returned value.
2. Move the reference to `self` into the closure.

Since Rust 1.26, you no longer *need* to return a boxed closure if you are only returning a single type. Instead, you can use `impl Trait`:

```
impl Returner {
    fn get<'a>(&'a self) -> impl Fn(i32) -> i32 + 'a {
        move |x| x + self.val
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Why is adding a lifetime to a trait with the plus operator (Iterator<Item = &Foo> + 'a) needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42028470/155423)
- [What is the correct way to return an Iterator (or any other trait)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423)
- [Returning a closure from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25445761/155423)
- [Conditionally iterate over one of several possible iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29760668/155423)