# "explicit lifetime required" when using a reference variable in a boxed future

Tags: rust, future, lifetime, borrowing, rust-tokio

I'm trying to use a struct created in `main()` and pass it on to a function that returns a boxed `Future`. However, I run into lifetime and borrowing issues and can't seem to resolve this cleanly.

Here is my struct and functions:

```
extern crate futures; // 0.1.21
extern crate tokio_core; // 0.1.17

use futures::{future::ok, Future};

pub struct SomeStruct {
    some_val: u32,
}

impl SomeStruct {
    pub fn do_something(&self, value: u32) -> u32 {
        // Do some work
        return self.some_val + value;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let core = tokio_core::reactor::Core::new().unwrap();
    let my_struct = SomeStruct { some_val: 10 };

    let future = get_future(&my_struct);
    core.run(future);

    let future2 = get_future(&my_struct);
    core.run(future2);
}

fn get_future(some_struct: &SomeStruct) -> Box<Future<Item = u32, Error = ()>> {
    let fut = ok(20).and_then(|val| {
        let result = some_struct.do_something(val);
        ok(result)
    });
    Box::new(fut)
}
```

On compiling, the following error occurs:

```
error[E0621]: explicit lifetime required in the type of `some_struct`
  --> src/main.rs:33:5
   |
28 | fn get_future(some_struct: &SomeStruct) -> Box<Future<Item = u32, Error = ()>> {
   |               ----------- consider changing the type of `some_struct` to `&'static SomeStruct`
...
33 |     Box::new(fut)
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime `'static` required
```

I suppose the error occurs because `SomeStruct` is used in the `Future` and might be used outside of `main()`s scope, hence the compiler asks me to change the lifetime to `'static`. Here is what I tried so far (unsuccessfully):

- Changing the lifetime to `'static` as suggested by the compiler, which creates borrowing issues in `main()`.
- Moving `val` by adding `ok(20).and_then(move |val| {` as suggested by the compiler, which creates issues in the second invocation of `get_future()`.
- Use the [lazy_static](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static) crate to explicitly initialize `SomeStruct` as static (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50740632/how-do-i-call-a-function-that-requires-a-static-lifetime-with-a-variable-create)), however I run into macro errors when trying that.

The whole example can be found [here](https://github.com/flock0/rust-lifetime-error). I have omitted some details to create an minimal example. The issues occur using `tokio-core` and `futures = "0.1"`. Migrating to version `"0.2"` is not an option unfortunately, due to a dependency of another library.

Comment: It's not the argument `val` that gets moved when you make a `move` closure; it's the environment (in this case represented by `some_struct`).

Answer (score 5):

Returning a boxed trait object has a `'static` bound by default. Do as the compiler suggests and provide an explicit lifetime, but not `'static`:

```rust
fn get_future<'a>(some_struct: &'a SomeStruct) -> Box<dyn Future<Item = u32, Error = ()> + 'a> {
    let fut = future::ok(20).and_then(move |val| {
        let result = some_struct.do_something(val);
        future::ok(result)
    });
    Box::new(fut)
}
```

You also have to use `move` to transfer ownership of `some_struct` to the closure and change `core` to be mutable. You should also handle potential errors resulting from `core.run`.

For the example provided, you could also return `impl Future`:

```rust
fn get_future<'a>(some_struct: &'a SomeStruct) -> impl Future<Item = u32, Error = ()> +'a {
    future::ok(20).and_then(move |val| {
        let result = some_struct.do_something(val);
        future::ok(result)
    })
}
```

See also:

- [How do I return a boxed closure from a method that has a reference to the struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40544020/155423)
- [Why is adding a lifetime to a trait with the plus operator (Iterator<Item = &Foo> + 'a) needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42028470/155423)
- [What is the correct way to return an Iterator (or any other trait)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423)

Comment: I was stuck fighting the borrow checker and was about ready to give up on Rust. And then read this answer when looking for some other issue...
This is the answer that made it click for me. Thanks!