# In Rust, can I return FnMut with a captured mutable reference, perhaps by specifying a generic lifetime?

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime, capture

Is it possible to specify a generic lifetime on `FnMut` in Rust for a function like this?

```
fn f1<'a, FRet:'a + FnMut() -> ()>(v: &'a mut i32) -> FRet {
   let mut fret = || {
       let i = v;
       println!("inside");
       // lots of complicated logic on captured var
       *i = 5;
   };

   return fret;
}
```

Right now I'm getting an error, that return is incompatible with `FRet`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning a closure from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445761/returning-a-closure-from-a-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has several issues. One is that you cannot make the function that returns a closure have a generic return type. `f1` being generic over `FRet` means that the caller gets to choose the `FRet`, and that obviously can't work when you're returning a closure you implement, and not something the caller can or should specify. This is why the compiler complains that `FRet` is incompatible with what you're actually returning.

The way to return a closure is by either boxing it or using the `impl Trait` return type that declares an unnamed type returned by the function:

```
fn f1(v: &mut i32) -> impl FnMut() {
   let fret = || {
       let i = v;
       println!("inside");
       // lots of complicated logic on captured var
       *i = 5;
   };

   fret
}
```

The above still doesn't compile with the compiler complaining that the closure is `FnOnce` rather than `FnMut`. This is because `&mut i32` is not `Copy`, so `let i = v` actually moves the reference out of `v` which makes the closure callable only once. That can be fixed with a reborrow, i.e. changing `let i = v` to `let i = &mut *v`.

After that the compiler will complain that the lifetime of reference is not captured by the closure, and that you can fix that by adding `+ '_`. (This is equivalent to declaring a lifetime `'a` and declaring `v: &'a mut i32` and `impl FnMut() + 'a`.) With this change the code compiles:

```
fn f1(v: &mut i32) -> impl FnMut() + '_ {
   let fret = || {
       let i = &mut *v;
       println!("inside");
       // lots of complicated logic on captured var
       *i = 5;
   };

   fret
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ec6dfeafe9c8ca4dae8197250b575b37)

Comment: Note the explicit reborrow isn't necessary, we just have to use `*v` instead of introducing `i`, and rust will automatically reborrow.

Comment: @cdhowie Good point. The answer assumes the OP had good reason to introduce `i`, which may not in fact be the case.