# How to refer to the type of a closure in a generic return value?

Tags: generics, rust, closures

I have a struct that contains a function, let's say of type `F: Fn() -> String`. And I want to initialize it in its constructor to a particular default function, which can later be overridden by the caller if they like.

```
struct Builder<F> {
    func: F,
}

fn new_builder() -> ??? {
    let hello = "hello".to_owned();
    Builder { func: move || hello }
}

impl<F: Fn() -> String> Builder<F> {
    fn build(self) -> String {
        (self.func)()
    }
}
```

But how do I write the return type of `new_builder()`, since `|| {}` has an anonymous type? I tried with `-> Builder<_>` but that fails ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=74f064786121119999414fe952976a55)), and suggests a solution that's not even syntactically valid:

```
error[E0121]: the placeholder `_` is not allowed within types on item signatures for return types
 --> src/lib.rs:5:29
  |
5 | fn new_builder() -> Builder<_> {
  |                     --------^-
  |                     |       |
  |                     |       not allowed in type signatures
  |                     help: replace with the correct return type: `Builder<[closure@src/lib.rs:6:21: 6:26]>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0121`.
```

I know I can solve it by making `Builder` non-generic with some boxing:

```
struct Builder {
    func: Box<dyn Fn() -> ()>,
}
```

But that incurs additional runtime overhead in the form of allocations and indirections, and might make it harder for the compiler to optimize, e.g. inline calls to `func`. This workaround is plenty fast in my practical situation, but I'm still wondering if Rust lets me stick to a purely static solution here.

Is there a way to make this work without resorting to references or boxing?

Comment: [`func: fn()`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=9afcb2d015cccea191360504e3eaed56) instead of a generic?

Comment: `fn()` is not meant to be used as a type directly. It's only meant to be used as a function pointer. Use `Box<Fn>` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning a closure from a method of a generic struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72050518/returning-a-closure-from-a-method-of-a-generic-struct)

Comment: @Finomnis I don't understand your comment: the playground link I posted shows that `func: fn()` is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that the type of a closure [cannot be written out in code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/closure.html).

Luckily, for exactly that reason, the `impl` keyword exists for return types:

```rust
struct Builder<F> {
    func: F,
}

fn new_builder() -> Builder<impl FnOnce() -> String> {
    let hello = "hello".to_owned();
    Builder {
        func: move || hello,
    }
}

impl<F: FnOnce() -> String> Builder<F> {
    fn build(self) -> String {
        (self.func)()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let builder = new_builder();
    println!("{}", builder.build());
}
```

Which means: "This is some unspecified type that the compiler will figure out. It's just important that this type implements `FnOnce() -> String`".

Other functions that use `new_builder` will then be able to access `func` as an `FnOnce() -> String` object.

Also note that I had to change the type to `FnOnce` because `func` in your case consumes the `hello` and is therefore only callable once.

Don't worry, though. `impl<F: FnOnce() -> String>` also includes `Fn` and `FnMut`, as they are also `FnOnce` implicitely.

Comment: This is a functional workaround, but I explicitly asked for a solution _without_ the performance penalty of indirections like `Box` or references.

Comment: As for XY-problem: it's a builder that will call the given function many times as part of the building process. I don't think the overhead of `Box` is an issue in practice, so the question is mostly academic, but I was still surprised that I couldn't make it work purely statically. It would be possible for any other trait, why does `Fn` need to be special in this regard?

Comment: The trouble with `fn` is that it doesn't accept a closure if the closure captures any variables: [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=8b431d480b4dc309d7a0832adf220202)